# Bubble sort not working properly

Tags: c, bubble-sort

```
do
{
    swap=false;
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
    if(pd[i]<pd[i+1])
    {
        int temp=pd[i];
            pd[i]=pd[i+1];
            pd[i+1]=temp;
        swap=true;
        }
    }
}
while(swap);
```

It only returns top two results properly and the rest as 0. I am sorting floats.

Comment: You mean, you are comparing floating points using `<` operator? .. you need to use epsilon. Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj: you only need epsilon values when doing equality checks. This is relational so it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am sorting floats.

In this case, `temp` must be of type `float`:

```
float temp=pd[i];
```

Otherwise, you're truncating `pd[i]` to `int` each time you do a swap.

Also, if your `float` array might contain [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)s, they'll require extra care in comparisons.

Comment: How stupid was i? , just forgot temp declare temp as float .

Comment: @aix can we compare floating points using `>` or `<` operators?!

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj: For sorting purposes, yes. Except for NaNs (they have somewhat tricky comparison semantics).

Comment: Yes you can compare float using '<' '>' operators.

Comment: +1, I would +2 if I could because you mention dealing with `NaN`, which people forget too often.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is of type `int`, but your array is of type `float`...

Comment: yes i got it, but thanks for the help anyway.