# comparing float variable

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most effective way for float and double comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)
>   [How dangerous is it to compare floating point values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values)

I have `const float M = 0.000001;` and `float input;`. I want to not equality check on them. But I know direct check has side effect `M != input`.  So, my question how I can compare two float value without side effect ?

Comment: What do you mean by "side effect"? Comparing floats has no side effects in the usual meaning of the term.

Comment: `M != input` isn't a (doesn't have any) side effect.

Comment: You can find an excellent article about floating point comparison here: [Comparing floating point numbers](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm). Basically, depending on your requirements, you can use - epsilon – absolute error: when the approx. range of values is known in advance - epsilon – relative error: when the approx. range of values is NOT known in advance - use the integer representation: when speed is of the essence.

Answer (score 3):

```
const double epsilon = 1e-12; 

if(fabs(input - M) < epsilon) //input == M
{
    //...
}
if(fabs(input - M) >= epsilon) // input != M
{
    //...
}
```

The smaller the value of epsilon the more accurate the comparison is, therefore the more the probablity that it will tell you that two values are not equal whereas you wanted them to be considered equal. The larger the value of epsilon, the more the probability that it will tell you the results are equal when in fact you wanted them to be not equal. The value of epsilon should be chosen in accordance with the specifics of the task at hand.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the actual value of `epsilon` is application-dependant, you're supposed to plug in a value that makes them "equal enough" for your usage.

Comment: @user1802858 Switch the comparison operator to `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing floats, you have to compare them for being "close" instead of "equal." There are multiple ways to define "close" based on what you need. However, a typical approach could be something like:

```
namespace FloatCmp {

const float Eps = 1e-6f;

bool eq(float a, float b, float eps = Eps) {
  return fabs(a - b) < eps;
}

//etc. for neq, lt, gt, ...

}
```

Then, use `FloatCmp::eq()` instead of `==` to compare floats.