# How '<=' condition work in c? The following simple program giving strange output :(

Tags: c, loops, output, conditional-statements

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x=0;
    while(x<=.2)
    {
        printf("%f\n",x);
        x=x+0.2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0.000000
```

But it should give..

```
0.000000
0.200000
```

I am posting question on stackoverflow for the first time. Please forgive me for my silliness.

Comment: Note too that you are mixing `float` (x) and `double` (0.2).

Comment: The linked answer doesn't fully explain things.
in this case, x is a float (single precision). 0.2 is a double. 
Changing the type of x to double, or replacing the add line with x = x + 0.2f should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. @ Weather Vane, I didn't know there are these problems with storing floating point data. Is there a simple way to solve the situation. I actually don't want to go that deep. I only need to the variable x to go from 0 to 0.6 (say) with steps 0.2. But it only goes to 0.4.I am editing the quetion to clarify in what situation I am facing the problem. And I need s simple solution. (I am not a programing student :( )

Comment: @luckykaa Thanks. I read your comment later. I guess no need to edit the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Siddhartha if you need exact values, use integers, e.g. `for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x) { printf("%f", x * .2); }`

Comment: You should avoid using equality operators with `float` and `double` (including `<=`  and `>=`). Check this question and the linked questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249796/comparing-float-variable

Comment: @luckykaa I wouldn't call this a solution, testing for equality will still go wrong in many cases. The duplicate explains quite well what the general problem is and how to avoid it

Comment: use while(x<=.2f), as by default .2 is double not float.

Comment: @luckykaa: While those changes would fix this one specific sample, it will not fix the problem if more additions are performed, as they will incur multiple rounding errors during repeated additions, rather than just one rounding error from the type conversion.

Comment: We've given you a simple solution: don't expect "==" (or the equal part of <=, >=) to be useful or predictable with floats. If you need floats, don't use ==. If you need exact loop counts, don't use floats.