# Floating point comparison revisited

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-lawyer, ieee-754

This topic has come up many times on StackOverflow, but I believe this is a new take.  Yes, I have read [Bruce Dawson's articles](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.ualberta.ca/~kbeach/phys420_580_2010/docs/ACM-Goldberg.pdf) and [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335601/768469).

As I understand it, on a typical system there are four basic problems when comparing floating-point numbers for equality:

1. Floating point calculations are not exact
2. Whether `a-b` is "small" depends on the scale of `a` and `b`
3. Whether `a-b` is "small" depends on the type of `a` and `b` (e.g. float, double, long double)
4. Floating point typically has +-infinity, NaN, and denormalized representations, any of which can interfere with a naïve formulation

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423299/768469) -- aka. "the Google approach" -- seems to be popular.  It does handle all of the tricky cases.  And it does scale the comparison very precisely, checking whether two values are within a fixed number of [ULPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of each other.  Thus, for example, a very large number compares "almost equal" to infinity.

However:

- It is very messy, in my opinion.
- It is not particularly portable, relying heavily on internal representations, using a union to read the bits from a float, etc.
- It only handles single-precision and double-precision IEEE 754 (in particular, no x86 long double)

I want something similar, but using standard C++ and handling long doubles.  By "standard", I mean C++03 if possible and C++11 if necessary.

Here is my attempt.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

namespace {
// Local version of frexp() that handles infinities specially.
template<typename T>
T my_frexp(const T num, int *exp)
{
    typedef std::numeric_limits<T> limits;

    // Treat +-infinity as +-(2^max_exponent).
    if (std::abs(num) > limits::max())
    {
        *exp = limits::max_exponent + 1;
        return std::copysign(0.5, num);
    }
    else return std::frexp(num, exp);
}
}

template<typename T>
bool almostEqual(const T a, const T b, const unsigned ulps=4)
{
    // Handle NaN.
    if (std::isnan(a) || std::isnan(b))
        return false;

    typedef std::numeric_limits<T> limits;

    // Handle very small and exactly equal values.
    if (std::abs(a-b) <= ulps * limits::denorm_min())
        return true;

    // frexp() does the wrong thing for zero.  But if we get this far
    // and either number is zero, then the other is too big, so just
    // handle that now.
    if (a == 0 || b == 0)
        return false;

    // Break the numbers into significand and exponent, sorting them by
    // exponent.
    int min_exp, max_exp;
    T min_frac = my_frexp(a, &min_exp);
    T max_frac = my_frexp(b, &max_exp);
    if (min_exp > max_exp)
    {
        std::swap(min_frac, max_frac);
        std::swap(min_exp, max_exp);
    }

    // Convert the smaller to the scale of the larger by adjusting its
    // significand.
    const T scaled_min_frac = std::ldexp(min_frac, min_exp-max_exp);

    // Since the significands are now in the same scale, and the larger
    // is in the range [0.5, 1), 1 ulp is just epsilon/2.
    return std::abs(max_frac-scaled_min_frac) <= ulps * limits::epsilon() / 2;
}
```

I claim that this code (a) handles all of the relevant cases, (b) does the same thing as the Google implementation for IEEE-754 single- and double-precision, and (c) is perfectly standard C++.

One or more of these claims is almost certainly wrong.  I will accept any answer that demonstrates such, preferably with a fix.  A good answer should include one or more of:

- Specific inputs differing by more than `ulps` Units in Last Place, but for which this function returns true (the bigger the difference, the better)
- Specific inputs differing by up to `ulps` Units in Last Place, but for which this function returns false (the smaller the difference, the better)
- Any case(s) I have missed
- Any way in which this code relies on undefined behavior or breaks depending on implementation-defined behavior.  (If possible, please cite a relevant spec.)
- Fixes for whatever problem(s) you identify
- Any way to simplify the code without breaking it

I intend to place a non-trivial bounty on this question.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @Eric:  You are right; I am using 2^ulps when I should just use ulps.  Fixing now.  As for the default, the Google folks disagree with you on whether a default is a good idea...  It likely depends on your particular application.  I will think it over for mine.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: The expression `factor * limits::epsilon / 2` converts `factor` to the floating-point type, which causes rounding errors for large values of `factor` that are not exactly representable. Likely, the routine is not intended to be used with such large values (millions of ULPs in `float`), so this ought to be specified as a limit on the routine rather than a bug. (Of course, the shift `1U << ulps` is also subject to error when `ulps` is large, but this is being removed.)

Comment: As an example of why a default of 4 ULP is bad, consider `1./49*49-1`. The mathematically exact result is 0, but the computed result (64-bit IEEE 754 binary) is -0x1p-53, an error exceeding 1e307 ULP of the exact result and almost 1e16 ULP of the computed result.

Comment: @Eric: So [the POSIX spec for frexp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/frexp.html) is also using "mantissa" incorrectly?  And the [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantissa) is also wrong?  Thanks again for the good comments.

Comment: @Nemo: “Mantissa” does not appear in the IEEE 754 standard. The Wikipedia page you point to is not a definition; it is a disambiguation page. The page it refers to, about “significand”, has a [usage note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand#Use_of_.22mantissa.22) on “mantissa”. The POSIX standard specifies POSIX; it is not authoritative on floating point or mathematics.

Comment: @Eric: The use of "mantissa" is so common in Computer Science that I would argue it is acceptable...  But since you are being so helpful -- and, truth be told, since I have an affinity for pedantry myself -- I have changed the comments and renamed the variables.  (I do not like any of the obvious abbreviations for "significand", so I went with "_frac".  Hope that is acceptable.)

Comment: Interesting, but is this a real question?

Comment: Are you sure that you leave the fp status flags as google code would?

Comment: @Matt - If you prefer, pretend I titled it "what is wrong with this code"?  It may not be phrased as a question, but it is definitely a question, and I think the current title will attract the right kind of people.

Comment: Re: "Floating point calculations are not exact": this is false. Floating point calculations **are** exact. The typical beginner's problem is the assumption that **conversions** from decimal (typically text) to binary are exact.

Comment: @PeteBecker floating point calculations are only interesting imasmuch they represent calculations with mathematical real numbers, and this representation is not exact. Decimal to binary convrrsions are but a particular case of this phenomenon.

Comment: @n.m. - floating-point math does **not** represent calculations with real numbers, and no amount of hacking will change that. Either you accept the way that floating-point math works on its own merits, or you spend inordinate amounts of time trying to work around a flawed mental model.

Comment: @PeteBecker: what do you mean by "do not represent"? There's a very well defined mapping from real numbers to floating point numbers. That's the "representation". You are free to ignore it if it's not useful to you, but I find it rather convenient.

Comment: @n.m. - maybe I misunderstood what you meant by "represent **calculations** with mathematical real numbers" [emphasis added]. There's a rough similarity, but calculations with floating-point numbers do **not** obey the same rules as real numbers.

Comment: "calculations with floating-point numbers do not obey the same rules as real numbers" -- sure they don't, that's why they are called inexact...

Answer (score 27):

### “Almost Equals” Is Not a Good Function

**4 is not an appropriate value:** The answer you point to states “Therefore, 4 should be enough for ordinary use” but contains no basis for that claim. In fact, there are ordinary situations in which numbers calculated in floating-point by different means may differ by many ULP even though they would be equal if calculated by exact mathematics. Therefore, there should be no default value for the tolerance; each user should be required to supply their own, hopefully based on thorough analysis of their code.

As an example of why a default of 4 ULP is bad, consider `1./49*49-1`. The mathematically exact result is 0, but the computed result (64-bit IEEE 754 binary) is 2<sup>−53</sup>, an error exceeding 10<sup>307</sup> ULP of the exact result and almost 10<sup>16</sup> ULP of the computed result.

**Sometimes, no value is appropriate:** In some cases, the tolerance cannot be relative to the values being compared, neither a mathematically exact relative tolerance nor a quantized ULP tolerance. For example, nearly every output value in an FFT is affected by nearly every input value, and the error in any one element is related to the magnitudes of other elements. So the amount of error we might get cannot be computed from the two values being compared; it is a function of other data in the FFT. An “almost equals” routine must be supplied additional context with information about the potential error.

**“Almost Equals” has poor mathematical properties:** This shows one of the shortcomings of “almost equals”: Scaling changes the results. The code below prints 1 and 0, indicating that `1.1` and `1.1 + 3*0x1p-52` are “almost equal,” but the same values multiplied by `.8` are not “almost equal.”

```
double x0 = 1.1;
double x1 = 1.1 + 3*0x1p-52;
std::cout << almostEqual(x0, x1) << "\n";
x0 *= .8;
x1 *= .8;
std::cout << almostEqual(x0, x1) << "\n";
```

Another failing is that it is not transitive; `almostEqual(a, b)` and `almostEqual(b, c)` does not imply `almostEqual(a, c)`.

### A Bug in Extreme Cases

`almostEqual(1.f, 1.f/11, 0x745d17)` incorrectly returns 1.

1.f/11 is 0x1.745d18p-4 (hexadecimal floating-point notation, meaning 1.745d18<sub>16</sub>•2<sup>−4</sup>). Subtracting this from 1 (which is 0x10p-4) yields 0xe.8ba2e8p-4. Since an ULP of 1 is 0x1p-23, that is 0xe.8ba2e8p19 ULP = 0xe8ba2e.8/2 ULP (shifted 20 bits and divided by 2, netting 19 bits) = 0x745d17.4 ULP. That exceeds the specified tolerance of 0x745d17, so the correct answer would be 0.

This error is caused by rounding in `max_frac-scaled_min_frac`.

An easy escape from this problem is to specify that `ulps` must be less than `.5/limits::epsilon`. Then rounding occurs in `max_frac-scaled_min_frac` only if the difference (even when rounded) exceeds `ulps`; if the difference is less than that, the subtraction is exact, by Sterbenz’ Lemma.

There was a suggestion about using `long double` to correct this. However, `long double` would not correct this. Consider comparing 1 and -0x1p-149f with `ulps` set to `1/limits::epsilon`. Unless your significand has 149 bits, the subtraction result rounds to 1, which is less than or equal to `1/limits::epsilon` ULP. Yet the mathematical difference clearly exceeds 1.

### Minor Note

The expression `factor * limits::epsilon / 2` converts `factor` to the floating-point type, which causes rounding errors for large values of `factor` that are not exactly representable. Likely, the routine is not intended to be used with such large values (millions of ULPs in `float`), so this ought to be specified as a limit on the routine rather than a bug.

Comment: Thank you for taking a close look at this, and nice catch (+1).  If this is the only bug, I think I am in pretty good shape.  I believe I could also fix this by using `long double` when computing `max_mant-scaled_min_mant`...  But restricting the legal range for `ulps` is probably a better idea.

Comment: I sent you Email but maybe it got filtered...  Could you please delete your comments on the question and move them into your answer?  They will be much easier to read that way, especially once I make your response the accepted one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Simplification:** You could avoid my_frexp by discarding the non finite cases first all-together:

```
if( ! std::isfinite(a) || ! std::isfinite(b) )
    return a == b;
```

It seems that isfinite is in C++11 at least

**EDIT** However, if intention is to have `limits::infinity()` within 1 ulp of `limits::max()`
then above simplification does not hold, but shouldn't my_frexp() return `limits::max_exponent+1` in `*exp`, rather than max_exponent+2 ?

Comment: // non finite floating point are either equal or not, but never almost

Comment: The questioner says, "for example, a very large number compares "almost equal" to infinity" with tones of apparent approval.

Comment: @SteveJessop ah good point, but then my_frexp should return max_exponent + 1 in *exp, not + 2, that miss-guided me :(

Comment: @Steve - Indeed, the spirit of this question is to mimic the (apparently popular) Google approach, but portably.  I would give up exact mimicry for a major improvement in portability, speed, or readability...  But if I can have my cake and eat it too, I will.  @aka.nice - `max_exponent + 2` is correct because `frexp` returns a fractional part in the range [0.5, 1), not [1, 2)

Comment: @Nemo I understand that, but 2^max_exponent is yet greater than max(), so why 2^(max_exponent+1) ??? It's more than twice max()

Comment: @aka.nice: Good point (+1).  I had the wrong definition of `max_exponent` in my head.  Fixed; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**FUTURE PROOFING**: If you ever want to extend such comparison to decimal float http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format in the future, and assuming that ldexp() and frexp() will handle such type with correct radix, then striclty speaking, 0.5 in `return std::copysign(0.5, num);` should be replaced by `T(1)/limits::radix()` - or `std::ldexp(T(1),-1)` or something... (I could not find a convenient constant in std::numeric_limits)

**EDIT** As Nemo commented, the assumptions that ldexp and frexp would use the correct FLOAT_RADIX are false, they stick with 2...

So a Future Proof portable version should also use:

- `std::scalbn(x,n)` instead of `std::ldexp(x,n)`
- `exp=std::ilogb(std::abs(x)),y=std::scalbn(x,-exp)` instead of `y=frexp(x,&exp)`
- now that above y in is [1,FLOAT_RADIX) instead of [T(1)/Float_Radix,1), return `copysign(T(1),num)` instead of 0.5 for infinite case of my_frexp, and test for `ulps*limits::epsilon()` instead of ulps*epsilon()/2

That also require a standard >= C++11

Comment: Good point.  But for real future-proofing, I would need to use the C++11 `std::ilogb` and `std::scalb` to do everything in the right radix.  Where I work, C++11 is not an option and probably won't be this decade...  Still, a perfectly portable C++11 implementation seems possible and worth having around.  Want to take a crack at adding it to this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Two disadvantages of your approach are that your implementation relies on several functions from `<cmath>` which are clearly only working for **floating point numbers found in the standard** and sadly are currently **not guaranteed to be `constexpr`** (While with GCC a `constexpr` version of your function will compile it won't with most other compilers).

The advantage of the Google approach over yours is that in C++20 you can replace the `union` (or a `reinterpret_cast`) in the GoogleTest version with [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) resulting in a **`constexpr` function**. Furthermore by checking for `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559` as well as using the newly introduced [`std::endian`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) you should be able to make sure that the assumed internal representation is correct.
By introducing **two custom traits** you can gain a lot of flexibility which allows you to extend the function to **non-standard floating types**:

- One trait for the **determining the unsigned integer of equal length** (in my code termed `UIntEquiv`): This way you can extend the code to arbitrary length floating point numbers by adding a specialisation (e.g. `template<> class UIntEquiv<16>` and using [GCC's `__uint128_t`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) or [Boost Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html)).
- Another for the actual **floating type** (in my code termed `FloatTrait`) with its sign, mantissa and exponent masks, as well as the representations for infinity and NaN. This way you might extend the comparison to non-C++-standard floating point numbers like a [`float256`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html) by adding yet another specialisation.

I inserted the code from my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/2b-t/02daa85ea5d83fc2cb96bfcf0570ab71) below:

```
#include <bit>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>


namespace detail {
  // Trait for excluding incomplete types: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44229779/9938686
  template <typename T, std::size_t = sizeof(T)>
  consteval std::true_type is_complete(T*) noexcept;

  consteval std::false_type is_complete(...) noexcept;
}

template <typename T>
using is_complete = decltype(detail::is_complete(std::declval<T*>()));

template <typename T>
static constexpr bool is_complete_v = is_complete<T>::value;

namespace detail {

  // Class for determining the corresponding unsigned integer type with equal length to the floating type
  template <std::size_t N>
  class UIntEquiv {
    protected:
      UIntEquiv() = delete;
      UIntEquiv(UIntEquiv const&) = delete;
      UIntEquiv(UIntEquiv&&) = delete;
      UIntEquiv& operator= (UIntEquiv const&) = delete;
      UIntEquiv& operator= (UIntEquiv&&) = delete;

      template<std::size_t M, typename std::enable_if_t<(M==sizeof(std::uint8_t))>* = nullptr>
      static consteval std::uint8_t determineUIntType() noexcept;
      template<std::size_t M, typename std::enable_if_t<(M==sizeof(std::uint16_t))>* = nullptr>
      static consteval std::uint16_t determineUIntType() noexcept;
      template<std::size_t M, typename std::enable_if_t<(M==sizeof(std::uint32_t))>* = nullptr>
      static consteval std::uint32_t determineUIntType() noexcept;
      template<std::size_t M, typename std::enable_if_t<(M==sizeof(std::uint64_t))>* = nullptr>
      static consteval std::uint64_t determineUIntType() noexcept;

    public:
      using type = decltype(determineUIntType<N>());
  };
  
  // You can potentially add specialisation of UIntEquiv for longer unsigned integer types here (e.g. for long double support).
  // e.g. GCC's __uint128_t: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html
  //      or Boost: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html
  //
  // template <>
  // class UIntEquiv<sizeof(__uint128_t)> {
  //   public:
  //     using type = __uint128_t;
  // };
  //
  // As long as std::numeric_limits<T> is specialized for the corresponding floating type and your architecture respects IEEE754 and stores
  // your floating point numbers with little-endian the code should compile correctly.
  // Therefore in case you have particular proprietary floating types with a different mantissa and exponent such as 
  // e.g. GCC's __float128: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html
  // the fastest solution is probably to specialize the std::numeric_limits<T> trait yourself.
  // Boost should already provide the fully specialized traits: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html

  template <std::size_t N>
  using UIntEquiv_t = typename UIntEquiv<N>::type;

  // In case your floating type does not respect IEEE754 or is not stored with little endian you will have to specialise the entire 
  // FloatTrait yourself:
  template <typename T>
  class FloatTrait;

  // Specialised trait for floating point number types according to IEEE754 stored with little endian
  template <typename T>
  requires std::is_floating_point_v<T> && std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559 && (std::endian::native == std::endian::little)
  class FloatTrait<T> {
    public:
      static constexpr std::size_t number_of_bytes {sizeof(T)};
      static constexpr std::size_t number_of_bits {number_of_bytes*std::numeric_limits<std::uint8_t>::digits};
      using Bytes = UIntEquiv_t<number_of_bytes>;

      static constexpr std::size_t number_of_sign_bits {1};
      static constexpr std::size_t number_of_fraction_bits {std::numeric_limits<T>::digits-1};
      static constexpr std::size_t number_of_exponent_bits {number_of_bits - number_of_sign_bits - number_of_fraction_bits};

      static constexpr Bytes sign_mask {Bytes{1} << (number_of_bits - 1)};
      static constexpr Bytes fraction_mask {~Bytes{0} >> (number_of_exponent_bits + 1)};
      static constexpr Bytes exponent_mask {~(sign_mask | fraction_mask)};

      static constexpr bool isNan(T const t) noexcept {
        auto const bytes {std::bit_cast<Bytes>(t)};
        auto const exponent_bytes {extractExponent(bytes)};
        auto const fraction_bytes {extractFraction(bytes)};
        return (exponent_bytes == exponent_mask) && (fraction_bytes != 0);
      }

      static constexpr bool isPosInf(T const t) noexcept {
        return isPos(t) && isInf(t);
      }

      static constexpr bool isNegInf(T const t) noexcept {
        return isNeg(t) && isInf(t);
      }

      static constexpr bool isNeg(T const t) noexcept {
        auto const bytes {std::bit_cast<Bytes>(t)};
        auto const sign_bytes {extractSign(bytes)};
        return sign_bytes != 0;
      }

      // Optional helper functions
      static constexpr bool isPos(T const t) noexcept {
        auto const bytes {std::bit_cast<Bytes>(t)};
        auto const sign_bytes {extractSign(bytes)};
        return sign_bytes == 0;
      }

      static constexpr bool isInf(T const t) noexcept {
        auto const bytes {std::bit_cast<Bytes>(t)};
        auto const exponent_bytes {extractExponent(bytes)};
        auto const fraction_bytes {extractFraction(bytes)};
        return (exponent_bytes == exponent_mask) && (fraction_bytes == 0);
      }

      static constexpr Bytes extractSign(Bytes const bytes) noexcept {
        return bytes & sign_mask;
      }

      static constexpr Bytes extractExponent(Bytes const bytes) noexcept {
        return bytes & exponent_mask;
      }

      static constexpr Bytes extractFraction(Bytes const bytes) noexcept {
        return bytes & fraction_mask;
      }

    protected:
      FloatTrait() = delete;
      FloatTrait(FloatTrait const&) = delete;
      FloatTrait(FloatTrait&&) = delete;
      FloatTrait& operator= (FloatTrait const&) = delete;
      FloatTrait& operator= (FloatTrait&&) = delete;
  };

  template <typename T>
  requires is_complete_v<FloatTrait<T>>
  class FloatView {
    public:
      using Trait = FloatTrait<T>;
      using Bytes = typename FloatTrait<T>::Bytes;

      explicit constexpr FloatView(T const t) noexcept
        : value{t} {
        return;
      }
      FloatView() = default;
      FloatView(FloatView const&) = default;
      FloatView(FloatView&&) = default;
      FloatView& operator= (FloatView const&) = default;
      FloatView& operator= (FloatView&&) = default;

      constexpr bool isAlmostEqual(FloatView const rhs, std::uint8_t const max_distance = 4) const noexcept {
        if (Trait::isNan(value) || Trait::isNan(rhs.value)) {
          return false;
        } else if (Trait::isNegInf(value) != Trait::isNegInf(rhs.value)) {
          return false;
        } else if (Trait::isPosInf(value) != Trait::isPosInf(rhs.value)) {
          return false;
        }
        return computeDistance(value, rhs.value) <= max_distance;
      }

    protected:
      T value;

      static constexpr Bytes signMagnitudeToBiased(T const t) noexcept {
        auto const b {std::bit_cast<Bytes>(t)};
        if (Trait::isNeg(t)) {
          return ~b + Bytes{1};
        } else {
          return Trait::sign_mask | b;
        }
      }

      static constexpr Bytes computeDistance(T const a, T const b) noexcept {
        auto const biased1 = signMagnitudeToBiased(a);
        auto const biased2 = signMagnitudeToBiased(b);
        return (biased1 >= biased2) ? (biased1 - biased2) : (biased2 - biased1);
      }
  };

}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool isAlmostEqual(T const lhs, T const rhs, std::uint8_t const max_distance = 4) noexcept {
  detail::FloatView<T> const a {lhs};
  detail::FloatView<T> const b {rhs};
  return a.isAlmostEqual(b, max_distance);
}
```

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iQCAjIdJXgq4lw2P)