# I write down first number to scan and after pressing enter it gives me 'not responding' message in windows

Tags: c, compilation

Why won't code work? After compiling I write down first number to scan and after pressing enter it gives me 'not responding' message in windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
 float x1, x2, y;
 scanf("%f %f", x1, x2);
 if (x1 < x2) {
    y = x1 / x2;
 } else if (x1 == x2) {
    y = x1 * x1 - 3;
 } else {
    y = 4 * x1 + 3 * x2;
 }
 printf("y = %f", y);
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: `scanf` requires that you pass the *addresses* of the values being read in. That's necessary because C is pass by value. So `scanf("%f %f", &x1, &x2);`

Comment: Once you fix that, you'll also want to be careful with your multiplications: `x1` and `x2` are floats, but if you multiply them by 4 and 3, the result will be ints. Make sure you use (e.g.) 4.0 and 3.0 in your calculations.

Comment: @MattPatenaude: No. For arithmetic operators, if one of the operand is `float` and the other is `int`. Resulting data type is `float`. This is called _usual arithmetic conversion_.

Comment: You may want to check that `x2 != 0` before doing `y = x1 / x2;`, too.

Comment: @smRaj I stand corrected! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to make your code working try to enter two numbers with space between them and only then press enter

update: also, you have to pass pointers to scanf, prefix `x1` and `x2` with `&`

also, check about [floating point numbers equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940316/floating-point-comparison-revisited)

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted. Since the question says "after compiling I write down first number to scan and after pressing enter it gives me 'not responding' message in windows", this actually seems to be the most relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Why your program throws 'not-responding' error ?

`scanf()` reads input from the standard input stream *stdin*.

```
int scanf(const char *restrict format, ... );
```

In your program,

```
scanf("%f %f", x1, x2);
```

the 2 '`%f`'s are the *conversion specifications*. The input is read and converted to `float`. The arguments following `"%f %f",` are taken as addresses wherein the converted values are to be stored. Pointers are expected. In your program, two `float *` are expected. You are providing `x1`, `x2`, both are of type `float` which is itself is wrong.

`x1` and `x2` are uninitialized and hence contains garbage values. Considering them as addresses and reading the values at them is  *invalid memory read*, resulting in **segmentation fault**. Hence, you receive not-responding error.

---

### Solution:

You should pass in proper arguments to `scanf()` (Read **[this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html)**);

To store `%f` which is of type `float`, you need `float*` which can hold the address of a `float` variable.

`&` operator gives you the address of the operand. You can solve your problem by,

```
scanf("%f %f",&x1,&x2);
```

Answer (score 0):

See IIya's answer. In addition:

```
scanf("%f %f", x1, x2);
```

You need to provide an address to a variable. So...

```
scanf("%f %f", &x1, &x2);
```