# How to decide if a template specialization exist

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, sfinae

I would like to check if a certain template specialization exist or not, where the general case is not defined.

Given:

```
template <typename T> struct A; // general definition not defined
template <> struct A<int> {};   // specialization defined for int
```

I would like to define a struct like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct IsDefined
{
    static const bool value = ???; // true if A<T> exist, false if it does not
};
```

Is there a way to do that (ideally without C++11)?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @HSchmale, The full problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44237528/how-to-write-template-overload-functions-with-fallback-triggered-if-template-arg

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using the fact that you can't apply `sizeof` to an incomplete type:

```
template <class T, std::size_t = sizeof(T)>
std::true_type is_complete_impl(T *);

std::false_type is_complete_impl(...);

template <class T>
using is_complete = decltype(is_complete_impl(std::declval<T*>()));
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acf0ecebbfe639ee)

---

Here is a slightly clunky, but working C++03 solution:

```
template <class T>
char is_complete_impl(char (*)[sizeof(T)]);

template <class>
char (&is_complete_impl(...))[2];

template <class T>
struct is_complete {
    enum { value = sizeof(is_complete_impl<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f44a23a9297c9452)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it without C++11?

Comment: @Fabio there you go.

Comment: Thanks! Is template in the second definition of is_complete_impl needed in the C++03 solution?

Comment: @Fabio just because I elected to pass the type explicitly rather than deduce it from a parameter :)

Comment: By the way, the second definition can be simplified a little bit as:  `template <class> long is_complete_impl(...);`

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative implementation always using the same trick @Quentin used

---

C++11 version

```
template<class First, std::size_t>
using first_t = First;

template<class T>
struct is_complete_type: std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_complete_type<first_t<T, sizeof(T)>> : std::true_type {};
```

[Example on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8j8AXFzqPhLEod6M)

---

Tentative C++03 version which does not work

```
template<typename First, std::size_t>
struct first { typedef First type; };

template<typename T>
struct is_complete_type { static const bool value = false; };

template<typename T>
struct is_complete_type< typename first<T, sizeof(T)>::type > { static const bool value = true; };
```

The error in this case is

> prog.cc:11:8: error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
>    struct is_complete_type< typename first::type > { static const bool value = true; };
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> prog.cc:11:8: note:         'T'

Comment: That `assert` statement in the example make code inside disappear in release build.