# C++ How to make an std::tuple type based on partial specializations?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I have a template with an integer parameter, but the base template is disabled by `static_assert()` like this. (I only want some certain specialization forms; I want any argument passed to the template to be prohibited except for certain arguments)

```
template<ItemID item_id> struct ItemTemplate{
    static_assert(item_id == -1,"Cann't use unspecialized ItemTemplate!");
    static ItemID id{ std::numeric_limits<ItemID>::max() };
    //...
};
```

I also have several specializations form for this template like (I often add or delete some of them)

```
template<> struct ItemTemplate<1>{
    static constexpr ItemID id{1};
    //..
};
template<> struct ItemTemplate<2>{
    static constexpr ItemID id{2};
    //...
};
```

Now I want to create a `std::tuple` which is initialised only by all available types. So in the above example, `ItemTemplate<1>` and `ItemTemplate<2>`, but not `ItemTemplate<3>` and other non-specialized types. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What is `ItemID`? Seems like `ItemTemplate<-1>` would not trigger the static assert. An [mcve] would be useful here.

Comment: It's std::uint32, and I don't think that's the point @Sam Varshavchik

Comment: No,  that's precisely the point. Using an `unsigned int` for an `ItemId`, `std::tuple<ItemTemplate<4>, ItemTemplate<5>>` throws a compilation error, since it obviously hits the static assert. Your question is unclear. If your question is really about how to enumerate all available specializations automatically, this is not possible in C++. You will have to explicitly implement this yourself.

Comment: Are the defined `ItemTemplate` versions guaranteed to be contiguous, as in `1, 2, 3 ... n`, or might you define `ItemTemplate<1>` and, for instance, `ItemTemplate<6>` without defining anything in between?

Comment: No, They are not guaranteed to be contiguous. I might use any non-negetive integer samller than 0xFFFFFFFF. @SilvioMayolo

Comment: So How to improve this ,add static_cast<std::intmax_t>(item_id) == -1 ? And it is about to enumerate all available specializations automatically. I only  wanna allow what I already defined, undefined values are expected to cause compile error.@SamVarshavchik May be an X-Y problem, though...

Comment: It is not possible to enumerate all existing specializations, in C++. You'll have to keep track of the specializations yourself. Even if the IDs were continuous, the static assert seems to prevent any kind of an SFINAE-based approach to enumerating the contiguous range. Which would also prevent SFINAE from enumerating the entire 32-bit range, via a brute-force solution, even if having the compiler to take days (weeks?) to churn through the 32-bit range isn't an issue.

Comment: Maybe another question, AFAIK, template and constexpr can be used to enumerating the entire 32-bit range(Although I think this will kill the compiler). But how to test exsitence of template spectialization? like, is_defined_v<1 or 2> returns true, is_defined_v<3 or 5 or 9> returns false?

Comment: template<ItemID item_id, typename = void> struct is_defined : false_type {};
 template<ItemID item_id> struct is_defined<item_id, void_t<ItemTemplate<item_id>>> : true_type {};
 template<ItemID item_id> constexpr bool is_defined_v = is_defined<item_id>::value;
This doesn't work(It always returns true).

Comment: [How to decide if a template specialization exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229676/how-to-decide-if-a-template-specialization-exist)

Comment: This approach to determine if a template specialization exists will not work in this case because of the static assert. A static assert cannot be used with template metaprogramming. The End.

Comment: Remove the implementation of `ItemTemplate`. Just declare it like `template<ItemID item_id> struct ItemTemplate;`. No need for static_assert. Provide definition only for specialized classes. Then when ever you instantiate `ItemTemplate` with some integer for which a specialization is not provided you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

I see a way but only if you forget the `static_assert()` denial way and define **only** the specializations of `ItemTemplate`.

The following is a simplified example where I define only some specializations of `foo` and the `foo` generic struct remain undefined.

```
template <std::size_t>
struct foo;

template <> struct foo<2U> {};
template <> struct foo<3U> {};
template <> struct foo<5U> {};
template <> struct foo<7U> {};
```

Now you need something to detect if a type is defined or not; by example, the following

```
template <typename T, std::size_t = sizeof(T)>
std::true_type existH (int);

template <typename>
std::false_type existH (long);

template <typename T>
using exist = decltype(existH<T>(0));
```

That is: from `exist<foo<0>>::value` you get `false` and from `exist<foo<2>>::value` you get `true`.

Now you need a list (usable compile time) of indexes of `foo` specialization defined from a lower limit (zero, by example) to an upper limit.

You can obtain it with

```
template <std::size_t I, std::size_t topI, typename,
          bool = (I == topI) || exist<foo<I>>::value>
struct fooIndexList;

template <std::size_t topI, std::size_t ... Ixs>
struct fooIndexList<topI, topI, std::index_sequence<Ixs...>, true>
 { using type = std::index_sequence<Ixs...>; };

template <std::size_t I, std::size_t topI, std::size_t ... Ixs>
struct fooIndexList<I, topI, std::index_sequence<Ixs...>, true>
 { using type = typename fooIndexList<I+1U, topI,
                   std::index_sequence<Ixs..., I>>::type; };

template <std::size_t I, std::size_t topI, std::size_t ... Ixs>
struct fooIndexList<I, topI, std::index_sequence<Ixs...>, false>
 { using type = typename fooIndexList<I+1U, topI,
                   std::index_sequence<Ixs...>>::type; };
```

Using `fooIndexList`, obtaining a `std::tuple` with all the `foo` defined (from zero to an upper limit) is very simple:

```
template <std::size_t ... Idx>
constexpr auto makeFooTupleH (std::index_sequence<Idx...> const &)
 { return std::make_tuple( foo<Idx>{} ... ); }

constexpr auto makeFooTuple ()
 { return makeFooTupleH(
      typename fooIndexList<0U, 100U, std::index_sequence<>>::type {}); }
```

In the example the upper limit is `100` but can be a template parameter of `makeFooTuple()`.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t = sizeof(T)>
std::true_type existH (int);

template <typename>
std::false_type existH (long);

template <typename T>
using exist = decltype(existH<T>(0));

template <std::size_t>
struct foo;

template <> struct foo<2U> {};
template <> struct foo<3U> {};
template <> struct foo<5U> {};
template <> struct foo<7U> {};

template <std::size_t I, std::size_t topI, typename,
          bool = (I == topI) || exist<foo<I>>::value>
struct fooIndexList;

template <std::size_t topI, std::size_t ... Ixs>
struct fooIndexList<topI, topI, std::index_sequence<Ixs...>, true>
 { using type = std::index_sequence<Ixs...>; };

template <std::size_t I, std::size_t topI, std::size_t ... Ixs>
struct fooIndexList<I, topI, std::index_sequence<Ixs...>, true>
 { using type = typename fooIndexList<I+1U, topI,
                   std::index_sequence<Ixs..., I>>::type; };

template <std::size_t I, std::size_t topI, std::size_t ... Ixs>
struct fooIndexList<I, topI, std::index_sequence<Ixs...>, false>
 { using type = typename fooIndexList<I+1U, topI,
                   std::index_sequence<Ixs...>>::type; };


template <std::size_t ... Idx>
constexpr auto makeFooTupleH (std::index_sequence<Idx...> const &)
 { return std::make_tuple( foo<Idx>{} ... ); }

constexpr auto makeFooTuple ()
 { return makeFooTupleH(
      typename fooIndexList<0U, 100U, std::index_sequence<>>::type {}); }


int main ()
 {
   auto ft = makeFooTuple();

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(ft),
                  std::tuple<foo<2U>, foo<3U>, foo<5U>, foo<7U>>>{}, "!");
 }
```

Limits:

- this solution works only if the generic `foo` isn't defined
- the code is C++14; if you need it in C++11 it's a little more complicated
- the upper limit in `makeFooTuple()` can't be a big number because `fooIndexList` is recursive so is limited by the compiler's recursion limit; you can bypass this limit but require mode code.