# using correct container type depending on a template being hashable

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am working on a C++ class that require a associative container (`map` or `unordered_map`)

my class looks like this:

```
    template<typename T>
    class myClass
    {
            static_assert(
                std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value,
                "content of myClass should be copy constructible"
            );
            // TODO: check if T::operator== exists

            /* if hash<T> is available */
            using container = std::unordered_map<T,T>;
            /* if hash<T> is unavailable */
            using container = std::map<T,T>;

        public:
            myClass() = default;

            [...]

        private:
            container m_mapping;
    }
```

I'd like the container to be automatically deduced from the template `T`:

- if `std::hash<T>` is available, we should be using `unordered_map` for performance.
- if `std::hash<T>` is not available, we should fall back to `map`

Is there a way to do that using c++ templates ?

Comment: So you would like the compiler to completely change the performance characteristics of your application without telling you?

Comment: Interesting question.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'd like the compiler him to choose the one I want without having to specify each time.

Comment: Why is specifying the type so onerous? It's obviously much simpler than writing some convoluted template code. Is this for a real application?

Comment: Not really. Bassically I am writting this helper class that will be included in a larger software. I might be the only one to use it, but i'd like to design it so it can easily be reusable by other. So it will probably not be used ut I'd like to learn the magic of modern c++ and know if such thing is possible.

Comment: Seems like yet more over-engineered, needless template programming to me. Simply template your class on what kind of collection you want to use.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question body. If you feel you need to add an answer that doesn't already exist then you can post your own answer. I have rolled back your edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with a fairly simple helper template:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct helper
{
    using type = std::map<T, T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct helper<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::hash<T>())>>
{
    using type = std::unordered_map<T, T>;
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e2f140d47b58b5f)

If `std::hash<T>()` is well-formed, that specialization is picked, otherwise SFINAE kicks in and the base template is used.  You can then adjust `myClass` to look something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class myClass
{
    //...
    using container = typename helper<T>::type;
    //...

private:
    //...
    container m_mapping;
    //...
};
```

---

Note that `std::void_t` was added in C++17.  If you don't have access to C++17 you can implement your own `void_t` as

```
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

Comment: Helper? How about naming it `select_map<T>`?  Upvoted anyhow,

Answer (score 2):

If I get You right it is pretty easily achievable in C++11 and newer. Firstly You can use conditional type from `type_traits` header. It looks like this:

```
std::conditional<test, Type1, Type2>
```

If `test` is true `conditional` has internal type `type` that is equal to `Type1'. Otherwise, it has member type equal to`Type2`.

Secondly, we need the `test` value from above and for that we have to write a trait. <s>I'll use example from here: [How to decide if a template specialization exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229676/how-to-decide-if-a-template-specialization-exist) - let's keep it simple.</s>

```
template<class T>
bool is_hashable_v = is_complete<std::hash<T>>::value;
```

EDIT: above does not work.
Let's use `enable_if` then:

```
template<class T, class = void>
struct is_hashable : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_hashable<
    T, 
    typename std::enable_if<decltype(std::hash<T>())>::type
> : std::true_type {};

template<class T>
bool is_hashable_v = is_hashable<T>::value;
```

So putting it all together, if you have above `is_hashable_v`:

```
using container =
    typename std::conditional<
        is_hashable_v<T>, 
        std::unordered_map<T, T>,
        std::map<T, T> 
    >::type;
```

Comment: I don't think disabled specializations of `std::hash` are guaranteed to be incomplete.

Comment: tested: they are not :/

Comment: I made a simpler is_hashable following the model from @MilesBudnek answer:

template <typename T, typename = void> std::false_type is_hashable;
template <typename T> std::true_type  is_hashable<T, void_t<decltype(std::hash<T>())>>;

Answer (score 0):

I realized that `std::hash<T>` is not a static function but rather a struct with an `operator()` and a constructor. Rather then trying to check for the existence of `std::hash<T>()` (the constructor) or `std::hash<T>()()` (the hashing function) we can simply check if `std::hash<T>` `is_constructible`

This makes the following code valid:

```
using container = typename std::conditional<
    std::is_constructible<std::hash<T>>::value,
    std::unordered_map<T,T>,
    std::map<T,T>
>::type;
```

Answer (score 0):

### With C++20

You can use concepts:

```
template<typename Key>
concept Hashable = requires(Key a) {
    { std::hash<Key>{}(a) } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
};

template<typename Key>
concept Sortable = requires(Key a, Key b) {
    { a < b } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
};

template<typename Key>
concept SortableNotHashable = Sortable<Key> && !Hashable<Key>;

template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct associative_map;

template <SortableNotHashable Key, typename Value>
struct associative_map<Key, Value>
: std::map<Key, Value> {
    using std::map<Key, Value>::map;
};

template <Hashable Key, typename Value>
struct associative_map<Key, Value> 
: std::unordered_map<Key, Value> {
    using std::unordered_map<Key, Value>::unordered_map;
};
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/3GjuXt

---

### Before C++ 20

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename = void>
struct associative_map
: std::map<Key, Value> {
    using std::map<Key, Value>::map;
};

template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct associative_map<Key, Value, std::void_t<decltype(std::hash<Key>())>> 
: std::unordered_map<Key, Value> {
    using std::unordered_map<Key, Value>::unordered_map;
};

// Usage:

class Number {
    int _i;
public:
    Number(int i): _i(i) {}
    operator int()const {return _i;}
};

int main() {
    // associative_map below is std::unordered_map
    associative_map<int, std::string> int2string = { {1, "one"} };
    int2string[7] = "seven";
    for(const auto& p : int2string) {
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << std::endl;
    }
    // associative_map below is std::map
    associative_map<Number, std::string> number2string = { {1, "one"} };
    number2string[7] = "seven";
    for(const auto& p : number2string) {
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```