# SFINAE to check if std::less will work

Tags: c++, sfinae

In my code I would like to have one operation happen before another if one object is less than another. However, if the type isn't comparable it doesn't matter the order. To achieve this, I've tried to use SFINAE:

```
template<typename T, typename = decltype(std::declval<std::less<T>>()(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<T>()))> 
bool ComparableAndLessThan(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    return std::less<T>()(lhs, rhs);
}
bool ComparableAndLessThan(...) {
    return false;
}

struct foo {};
int main()
{
    foo a,b;
    if (ComparableAndLessThan(a, b)) {
        std::cout << "a first" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "b first" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However this did not work. If I create an object without giving it a operator< or a std::less specialization, I get this error.

```
error C2678: binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const foo' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
note: could be 'bool std::operator <(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
note: or       'bool std::operator <(const std::error_code &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
note: while trying to match the argument list '(const foo, const foo)'
note: while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<T>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
       with
       [
           T=foo,
           _Ty=foo
       ]
```

I'm assuming because the declaration exists, SFINAE doesn't see this as an error, even though the implementation causes an error. Is there any way to check if std::less can be used on a templated type?

Comment: As an aside: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: Oops on the `void main()`. Ha, it started off as `void test4()` but I wasn't thinking when I renamed. Edited code to use int instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code has two issues. First is simple to fix: default template arguments are not part of overload resolution, and should not be used for SFINAE-type resolution. There is a canonical fix to it, your make a non-type template parameter of type `your_decltype`* and default it `nullptr`.

The second issue is harder. Even with fix above, SFINAE doesn't work because there is no substitute error. `std::less<T>` is **defined** for every `T`, it is just there is a compilation error when `operator<` is called. One way to solve it would be to directly use `operator<` for your types:

```
template<typename T, 
     decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>())* = nullptr> 
bool ComparableAndLessThan(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    return std::less<T>()(lhs, rhs);
}
bool ComparableAndLessThan(...) {
    return false;
}
```

But it's likely not want you want. I do not know how to make it work with very wildly defined `std::less`.

Comment: Okay. So I can check for `operator<`, but there's no way to check if there is a specialization of std::less. I guess I'll do this. Then allow them to pass a comparator that defaults to `std::less<void>`. If I find it's equal to `std::less<void>` I'll check for `operator<`. If it's not equal, I'll assume their comparator works, and if they get an error, it's their fault.

Comment: sorry but... about the "default template arguments are not part of overload resolution, and should not be used for SFINAE-type resolution" part... are you sure? Do you mean that you can't use `template<typename T, typename = decltype( std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>())>` to SFINAE purposes?

Comment: @max66 you can, but it is not a part of the function signature, and as such, does not participate in overload resolution. More details: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Comment: @JonathanGawrych I am not saying there is no way, but I do not know of any.

Comment: @SergeyA - so when you write "should not be used for SFINAE-type resolution", do you mean "you can use it for SFINAE but is dangerous so is better to avoid it"?

Comment: @max66, no, I mean it will not allow you to select one of two otherwise identical overloads over another. As a result, it's best not to get into habit of using it.

Answer (score 3):

I want to show what the issue is with a simple example.

First, [SergeyA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48954078/2805305) is correct that you need to make it non-type template parameter defaulted `nullptr`.

Now to why it doesn't work.

Because `operator()` of `std::less` is not SFINAE friendly. Let me show you what I mean:

```
template <class T> struct Not_working
{
    // not SFINAE friendly
    auto operator()(T a, T b) { return a < b; }
};
```

This is what `std::less::operator()` looks like. The method `operator()` is defined unconditionally. Even if `T` has a `<` or not, the `operator()` exists and has a **valid declaration**. The error is in the body of the function.

When you use `Not_working::operator()` in an SFINAE context the body of it is **not an immediate context** so for the purpose of SFINAE the `Not_working::operator()` is valid and not a failure. So the specialization is kept for the overload set and then we have an error.

In order to be usable in an SFINAE the `operator()` must not participate in overload resolution if there are errors in the body. In other words it itself must be SFINAEd:

```
template <class T> struct Working
{
    // SFINAE friendly
    template <class TT = T, decltype(TT{} < TT{})* = nullptr>
    auto operator()(T a, T b) { return a < b; }
};
```

Now when `Working::operator()` is used in an SFINAE context like in your `ComparableAndLessThan` then we will have an substitution failure that is not an error so SFINAE will work as expected.

In my humble opinion not making such members SFINAE friendly is an oversight of the committee but there could be some factors I am not considering.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write it like this.

```
template<typename T, typename F = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>()), bool>::value, bool>::type> 
F ComparableAndLessThan(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    return std::less<T>()(lhs, rhs);
}
bool ComparableAndLessThan(...) {
    return false;
}
```

Changed your check to instead see if `decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>())` yields a bool.

Answer (score -1):

SFINAE only works in the immediate context of the template. In your case, the error happens within std::less::operator()
You can however first test if operator < is available; If not, check wether a specialisation of std::less is available. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229676/how-to-decide-if-a-template-specialization-exist).

Comment: The only problem is std::less is still a complete type even if it doesn't have a specialization :/