# IOS: Get two digits of a double (€) NOT to display the value, just return it

Tags: ios, xcode, compare, double, limit

*I´ve read a lot of posts about this but all of them were to limit the number digits to show them(NSString) .In my case I have:*

I compare two double values(wich are the "same"), each of them got from different mathematical operations. For example: (4.800000 and 4.800000)

double result1=4.800000, result2=4.800000

//compare the results:

```
if(result1==result2){
    msg.text=@"well done!!";        
}else if(result1>result2){
    msg.text=@"continue your work";    
}
```

"I´m working with money (4,80€)"

In the msg label i get "continue your work" message, not the "well done". I don´t even know if the comparison is done in a correct way.

I think that the best idea would be to limit 4.800000 to 4.80 in order to delete small values and get a exact comparison.(how could i do this?)
I DONT WANT to limit the number to two digits just to PRINT the solution, I want to WORK with that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
double a = 2.55000, b = 2.55002;
if(fabs(a-b)<1e-3) {
    // code here, a == b
} else {
   // code here, a != b
}
```

Comment: Cool idea but: if a =2.440000 and b=2.42000 appears the code a==b

Comment: @asierReisa, show me your ObjC code where a==b and a=2.44 and b=2.42

Comment: Here is the code:  if((dineroObjetivo-sumadinerodejado)<1e-3) {
        mensajeResultado.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"MUY BIEN!! resta: %f",dineroObjetivo-sumadinerodejado];
      
    } else {
        //juego completado pero dinero de sobra
        mensajeResultado.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Te sobra dinero: %f, intenta usar los cambios que tienes",(sumadinerodejado-dineroObjetivo)];

    }

Comment: But nothing...if i get 4.200 & 4.199 its OK but if i get a higher value as 4.200 & 4.350 -->error

Comment: in your code you are not using abs\fabs, so its clear why its not working correctly

Comment: sorry, i have changed but i get the same problem

Comment: YEah! there we go!! i changed abs for fabs and the aproblemas are gone! Anddrew I really appreciate your patience and help, Its an important work for the university that i have to finish tomorrow! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

use `floor(<#double#>)` to round down OR just subtract them and floor the result.

Answer (score 0):

For a nice answer to this problem see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335601/474896

Which could be summarized as a simple as:

```
if (fabs(x-y) < FLT_EPSILON) {/* ... */}
```

However since you you're working with money values you should check out `NSDecimalNumber`.

Or as Marcus Zarra puts it:

> ["If you are dealing with currency at all, then you should be using
>   NSDecimalNumber."](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/).