# search part of an item in a set

Tags: c++, key, set, std-pair

is there a way to search a part of an item in a set? I have a set of pairs `std::set< std::pair<double, unsigned> >` and want to search for an item via a given double. Is there any way I can do this convenient instead of manually creating a pair and searching for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your set uses the standard comparison operator to define the ordering within the set, and given that the `double` element comes first in the pair, the sorting order inside the set is defined primarily by the `double` elements of the pair (and only for pairs that share the `double` element will the second element be taken into account for the ordering).

Therefore, the only thing you need to do is to define a comparison operator that compares pairs with single doubles in both directions (note I use C++11 syntax in several places):

```
using std::pair;
using std::set;

typedef pair<double,unsigned>  pair_t;
typedef set<pair_t>            set_t;
typedef set_t::iterator        it_t;

struct doublecmp
{
  /* Compare pair with double. */
  bool operator()(const pair_t &p, double d)
  { return (p.first < d); }

  /* Compare double with pair. */
  bool operator()(double d, const pair_t &p)
  { return (d < p.first); }
};
```

And with this in place, you can use the `std::equal_range` algorithm to find the range of all pairs in the set that have a given `double d` as first element:

```
std::equal_range(begin(s),end(s),d,doublecmp());
```

If this is compiled with optimization, the instantiation of `doublecmp()` is a no-op.

You'll find a fully working code example [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4gfsag$15).

**Why does this work?**
Given that your set is declared as `set<pair<double,unsigned>>`, you are using the default comparison operator `less<pair<double,unsigned>>`, which is the same as the standard `operator<` for `pair`. That is defined as the lexicographic ordering (20.3.3/2 in C++11, or 20.2.2/2 in C++03), therefore the first element of each pair is the primary sorting criterion.

**Caveat 1** The solution will generally not work if you declare your set to use a different comparison operator than the default one. It also won't work if the part of the pair you use as searching criterion is the second, rather than the first element.

**Caveat 2** The data type used in the search criterion is a floating point type. Equality checks (including the `operator<`-based indirect equality checking performed by `std::equal_range`) for floating point numbers are generally difficult. The `double` you are searching for may have been computed in a way that suggests it should be mathematically identical to certain values in the set, but `std::equality_range` might not find them (nor would `std::find_if` suggested in other answers). For equality checks it is generally a good idea to allow for a small ("up to some epsilon") difference between the value you are looking for and the values you consider as matches. You can accomplish this by replacing `std::equal_range` with explicit calls to `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` and taking into account a parameter `epsilon`:

```
pair<it_t,it_t> find_range(set_t &s, double d, double epsilon)
{
   return {std::lower_bound(begin(s),end(s),d - epsilon,doublecmp()),
           std::upper_bound(begin(s),end(s),d + epsilon,doublecmp())};
}
```

This leaves the question how to determine the right value for `epsilon`. This is generally difficult. It is usually computed as an integer multiple of `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon`, but choosing the right factor can be tricky. You'll find more information about this in [How dangerous is it to compare floating point values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values).

Comment: +1, very nice. It didn't even occur to me that `equal_range` would work (caveats aside).

Answer (score 1):

Since the set isn't ordered according to your search criteria, you could use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a predicate that checks only the pair's `first` element. This will return an iterator to the first matching element, with the usual caveats about comparing floating point numbers for equality.

```
double value = 42.;
auto it = std::find_if(the_set.begin(), the_set.end(), 
                       [&value](const std::pair<double, unsigned>& p) { return p.first==value; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for or not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


struct Finder{
    template<typename Value>
    bool operator()(const Value& first, const Value& v) const{
        return first == v;      
    }
};

template <typename Value>
struct FirstValueValue{
    FirstValueValue(const Value& value): value(value){};
    template<typename Pair>
    bool operator()(const Pair& p) const{
        return p.first == value;
    }
    Value value;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    typedef std::set<std::pair<double,unsigned int> > SetOfPairs;
    SetOfPairs myset;
    myset.insert(std::make_pair(2.0,1));
    myset.insert(std::make_pair(5.7,2));


    Finder finder;
    double v = 2.0;
    for(SetOfPairs::iterator it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); it++){

        if( finder(it->first,v) ){
            cout << "found value " << v << std::endl;
        }
    }

    FirstValueValue<double> find_double_two(2.0);

    myset.insert(std::make_pair(2.0,100));
    unsigned int count =    std::count_if(myset.begin(),myset.end(),find_double_two);
    cout << "found " << count << " occurances of " << find_double_two.value;

}
```

Which prints out:

```
found value 2
found 2 occurances of 2
```

I don't know what your needs are or if boost libraries are allowed but you could look into Boost Multi Index if you have to index off one part of the pair a lot.

Hope this helps.  Good luck.