# Right way to compare float or double values?

Tags: iphone, floating-point, comparison

I have code to compare float or double values in cellforrowAtIndexPath. I am comparing it and setting color to tableView cell on evaluating compare value.But some times , it is not getting inside the not equal to condition while value is different.Can any body tell me what is the right way I can use to compare two float or double values.The log inside not equal to condition(!=) is not printing sometimes.

My code is as follows:---

```
double br_preVal=[[[prevDict valueForKey:@"bestbuyprice"] valueForKey:@"text"] doubleValue];
double br_nxtVal=[[[tempDic valueForKey:@"bestbuyprice"] valueForKey:@"text"] doubleValue];

double sr_preVal=[[[prevDict valueForKey:@"bestsellprice"] valueForKey:@"text"] doubleValue];
double sr_nxtVal=[[[tempDic valueForKey:@"bestsellprice"] valueForKey:@"text"] doubleValue];


if (br_nxtVal!=br_preVal) {

    NSLog(@"buy rate Not equal === and values %f,%f",br_preVal,br_nxtVal);

    if (br_nxtVal>br_preVal) {
        [mwCell.buyRate setBackgroundColor:t.socketHighbgColor];
        mwCell.buyRate.textColor=t.socketHighfgColor;

        [celllc replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:t.socketHighbgColor];
    }else{
        [mwCell.buyRate setBackgroundColor:t.socketLowbgColor];
        mwCell.buyRate.textColor=t.socketLowfgColor;

        [celllc replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:t.socketLowbgColor];
    }
}else{

    mwCell.buyRate.backgroundColor=[celllc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    mwCell.buyRate.textColor=([[celllc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:t.socketLowbgColor])?t.socketLowfgColor:t.socketHighfgColor;
}

if (sr_nxtVal!=sr_preVal) {

    NSLog(@"sell rate Not equal === and values ==  %f,%f",sr_preVal,sr_nxtVal);

    if (sr_nxtVal>sr_preVal) {
        [mwCell.sellRate setBackgroundColor:t.socketHighbgColor];
        [mwCell.sellRate setTextColor:t.socketHighfgColor];

        [cellrc replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:t.socketHighbgColor];
    }else{
        [mwCell.sellRate setBackgroundColor:t.socketLowbgColor];
        [mwCell.sellRate setTextColor:t.socketLowfgColor];

        [cellrc replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:t.socketLowbgColor];
    }
}else{

    mwCell.sellRate.backgroundColor=[cellrc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    mwCell.sellRate.textColor=([[cellrc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:t.socketLowbgColor])?t.socketLowfgColor:t.socketHighfgColor;
}

mwCell.buyRate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",br_nxtVal];
mwCell.sellRate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",sr_nxtVal];
```

**float values are some thing like this  2396.250000**

Comment: In first place, I don't think you need to use floating-point numbers as identifiers...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How dangerous is it to compare floating point values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I know that ,but those answers didn't work for me so, I post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing like this

```
#define kVerySmallValue (0.000001)
  if(fabsf(br_nxtVal - br_preVal) < kVerySmallValue) {
  //// Your code
  }
```

Comment: but , few times it skips condition it data comes fastly

Answer (score 1):

By Deafult, a decimal vale like `3.13` is `double` so if you have to assign it to in `float` varibale do this:

```
float f = 3.14f;//now it is float
```

see this Example:

```
float f = 3.14;
if(f == 3.14)
{
   NSLog(@"Equal");
}
else
{ 
   NSLog(@"Not Equal");
}
```

it will print not Equal..

So the best way to do this is:

```
float f = 3.14;
    if(f == 3.14f)
    {
       NSLog(@"Equal");
    }
    else
    { 
       NSLog(@"Not Equal");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to compare float values is to use range

```
if(4.0<=a&&a<=4.5)
```

or you can use `fabs(number)< comparator >fabs(number)`

Comment: brute force use abs() or typecast to int