# Why is cholesky decomposition not giving me the same result as simply inverting the matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, optimization, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

## Setting to reproduce my Minimal Working Example

I have the following matrix

```
K <- matrix(c(1.250000e+00, 3.366892e-07, 4.641930e-10, 1.455736e-08, 1.049863e-06, 
              3.366892e-07, 1.250000e+00, 5.482775e-01, 8.606555e-01, 9.776887e-01,
              4.641930e-10, 5.482775e-01, 1.250000e+00, 8.603413e-01, 4.246732e-01,
              1.455736e-08, 8.606555e-01, 8.603413e-01, 1.250000e+00, 7.490100e-01,
              1.049863e-06, 9.776887e-01, 4.246732e-01, 7.490100e-01, 1.250000e+00), nrow=5)
```

and the following vector

```
y <- matrix(c(39.13892, 12.34428, 12.38426, 14.71951, 10.52160), nrow=5)
```

## Problem

I want to calculate the product between the inverse of `K` and the vector `y`.

#### Naive Method - It works

The naive method works (I have a way of checking, but doesn't matter here)

```
solve(K) %*% y
```

```
           [,1]
[1,] 31.3111308
[2,]  3.0620869
[3,]  3.7383357
[4,]  6.6257060
[5,]  0.7820081
```

#### Cholesky Decomposition - Fails

However the "clever" method fails. I use cholesky decomposition which gives me an upper triangular matrix. Then I solve the system `L z = y` by backward substitution and the system `L^T x = L^{-1} y` by forward substitution.

```
L <- chol(K)  ## upper triangular
forwardsolve(t(L), backsolve(L, y))
```

```
          [,1]
[1,]  31.31112
[2,] -14.16259
[3,]   9.84534
[4,]  39.67900
[5,]  33.54842
```

What is happening? This matrix  `K` and this vector 'y` are just an example. It happens with many other similar vectors and matrices. Why?

Comment: Maybe `chol2inv(chol(K)) %*% y`?

Comment: @Matt incredibly, this gives an answer that is different from both! 

`[,1]
[1,]  39.138913
[2,] -14.385526
[3,]  -5.993738
[4,]  27.188652
[5,]   6.766934`

Comment: @Matt I think someone had a similar problem [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147654/cholesky-factorization-and-forward-substitution-less-accurate-than-inversion) but none really managed to answer

Comment: `chol2inv(chol(K)) %*% y` gives the results as `solve(K) %*% y` for me. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718334/comparing-matrix-inversions-in-r-what-is-wrong-with-the-cholesky-method)

Comment: @Matt that’s right, same result! do you know if chol2inv should be preferred to solving the system using forwardsolve and backsolve?

Comment: @Matt I think I managed to find a way around it, not sure why it works though. I found out that doing `backsolve(L, forwardsolve(t(myL), ytrain))` actually works..

Comment: I meant `backsolve(L, forwardsolve(t(L), ytrain))` of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is that  when taking the inverse of a product one must reverse the product of the inverses:

```
solve(A %*% B) = solve(B) %*% solve(A)
```

In the question the order was not reversed.

If `R = chol(K)` where we use `R` to emphasize that it is upper right triangular then:

```
solve(K, y)
= solve(t(R) %*% R, y)   since K = t(R) %*% R
= solve(t(R) %*% R) %*% y
= solve(R) %*% solve(t(R)) %*% y  note that we have reversed the order
= solve(R) %*% solve(t(R), y)
= backsolve(R, forwardsolve(t(R), y))
```

In the last line we used the fact that the transpose of R is lower left triangular and `forwardsolve` works on such matrices whereas `backsolve` works on upper right triangular matrices.

We can check that this does give the same answer as using `solve` direclty:

```
R = chol(K)
all.equal(backsolve(R, forwardsolve(t(R), y)), solve(K, y))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a partial answer, but it's better than nothing. Basically finding K^{-1}y is equivalent to solving the following system

[image: system]

Writing this using the cholesky decomposition we have

[image: cholesky]

Basically we now consider `Lz` to be our variable first, call it `x`

[image: substitution]

and since `L` is upper-triangular, it's transpose is lower-triangular, so that we can use `forwardsolve` to find `x`

```
forwardsolve(t(L), y)
```

Once we've found `x`, we can just remember what it means, i.e.

[image: finalsystem]

so that we can use 'backsolve`to find`z`

```
backsolve(L, forwardsolve(t(L), y))
```

and this gives the correct answer. Not sure why the other way around does't work as well.