# checking range in C++ using if if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, range

I was trying to use if statement to check the number entered fits in the range I am allowing. But apparently it is not working. Here's my if statement

The user inputs the weight and I check if it's between the small/top weight

```
  const float SMALL_WEIGHT        = 2.3f;      // low end 1st range weight
  const float TOP_SMALL_WEIGHT    = 4.3f;      // top end 1st range weight

  cout << "Enter the weight of the laptop: ";
  cin >> weight;

            if ( weight < SMALL_WEIGHT && weight > TOP_SMALL_WEIGHT )
           {
              cout << "The weight " << weight << " is not between "
                   << SMALL_WEIGHT << " and " << TOP_WEIGHT << endl;
              return 1;
           }
```

I tried using logical or || but it's still not working.

edit: this is the whole code

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <iomanip>    
using namespace std;

const float SALE_START_PRICE    = 500.0f;    // discount if more than 500
const float DISCOUNT_PCT        = .15f;      // 15% discount
const float TAX_PCT             = .075f;     // tax is 7.5%

const float SMALL_WEIGHT        = 2.3f;      // low end 1st range weight
const float TOP_SMALL_WEIGHT    = 4.3f;      // top end 1st range weight
const float TOP_MID_WEIGHT      = 5.8f;      // top 2nd range weight
const float TOP_WEIGHT          = 7.9f;      // top 3rd range weight

const float SMALL_SHIP          = 5.4f;      // 1st range basic ship charge
const float MID_SHIP            = 5.8f;      // 2nd range basic ship charge
const float TOP_SHIP            = 6.2f;      // 3rd range basic ship charge

const float SMALL_SHIP_PCT      = .025f;
const float MID_SHIP_PCT        = 2.75f;
const float TOP_SHIP_PCT        = 3.5;

int main()
{
   float    price, weight;
   float    discountAmount, salePrice;                              
   float    taxAmount, shippingCharges, totalSaleAmount;

   cout << "Enter the original price of the laptop: ";             
   cin  >> price;

   cout << "Enter the weight of the laptop: ";
   cin >> weight;


   if ( weight < SMALL_WEIGHT && weight > TOP_SMALL_WEIGHT )
   {
      cout << "The weight " << weight << " is not between "
           << SMALL_WEIGHT << " and " << TOP_WEIGHT << endl;
      return 1;
   }

   if ( price > SALE_START_PRICE )
   {
      discountAmount =  price * DISCOUNT_PCT;
   }
   else
       discountAmount = 0.00;

   taxAmount = price * TAX_PCT;
   salePrice = price - discountAmount;


   if (weight < TOP_SMALL_WEIGHT)
      shippingCharges = SMALL_SHIP + ( salePrice * SMALL_SHIP_PCT );
   else if ( weight >= TOP_SMALL_WEIGHT && weight < MID_SHIP )
      shippingCharges = MID_SHIP + ( salePrice * MID_SHIP_PCT);
   else
      shippingCharges = TOP_SHIP + ( salePrice * TOP_SHIP_PCT );

   totalSaleAmount = salePrice + taxAmount + shippingCharges;

   cout <<  fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
   cout << "The original price : $" << price << endl;
   cout << "The discount       : $" << discountAmount << endl;
   cout << "The sale price     : $" << salePrice << endl;
   cout << "The sales tax      : $" << taxAmount << endl;
   cout << "The shipping       : $" << shippingCharges << endl << endl;
   cout << "The total sale     : $" << totalSaleAmount << endl;

   return 0;                                      
}
```

Comment: `||` should work. Maybe you should post the full code.

Comment: What type is weight declared as?

Comment: Float, I posted the whole code

Comment: Or better, define `not working`. Is `return 1;` is what `not working` means?

Comment: you can see this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison

Answer (score 3):

`weight` cannot be both smaller than `SMALL_WEIGHT` and bigger than `TOP_SMALL_WEIGHT`.

I think you want to use a logical or `||` So it becomes:

```
if (weight < SMALL_WEIGHT || weight > TOP_SMALL_WEIGHT)
{
    cout << "The weight " << weight << " is not between "
         << SMALL_WEIGHT << " and " << TOP_WEIGHT << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to press post of the exact same answer, :P.

Comment: Thank you all, when I changed it to or. I try and put the weight to 5.5 (which is between the range) it gives the error message as if I entered something outside of it.

Comment: @na9er 5.5 is outside the range according to the code you posted.

Comment: @k4rlsson excuse my ignorance. I see my mistake now

Comment: For range I would use && as it will also work for comparing multiple ranges.