# Compare two float values - not identical

Tags: php, compare

I´ve a strange problem and I hope you can help me.

I´ve two values at the beginning:

```
var_dump($order_sum);
var_dump($orders_obj->getOrders_preisliste_sum ());
var_dump($order_sum != $orders_obj->getOrders_preisliste_sum ());
```

Result:

```
float(49.7) 
string(7) "49.7000" 
bool(true)
```

Here all is okay, but why is that way also "true" if I compare them?

```
var_dump($order_sum);
var_dump(floatval($orders_obj->getOrders_preisliste_sum ()));
var_dump($order_sum != floatval($orders_obj->getOrders_preisliste_sum ()));
```

Result:

```
float(49.7) 
float(49.7) 
bool(true) <---
```

In my opinion it should be the same, but here PHP displays it as a different.

Comment: [Read some of this until you get the gist of what they are saying](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Floating point precision is more complex than it first appears. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values) might also provide some insight.

Comment: @Adam: They should both be `49.700000000000003`

Comment: I didn't think anything of it. Thanks for help. I´ve rounded the values and now all is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could use bccomp function (bcmath extension) to compare your float values : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php.
Your values are actually not equals because of floating point precision as Adam just mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, a new feature that I have not used yet. :-)