# What is the difference between == and <= in this case

Tags: objective-c, operators

I was working on making a game, and I was wondering why the construct with the == operator doesn't work while the lower one does. I used an NSLog message afterwards to test.

```
    if (pipe.position.x == bird.position.x){ no idea why this doesn't work
    if ((pipe.position.x <= bird.position.x) & (pipe.position.x > bird.position.x - 1)){
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because one (or both) of the `position.x`'s are a floating-point<sup>2</sup> value with a non-zero difference<sup>1</sup> between the two position values such that only the second condition is true.

Since `p <= b` is true for all values that make `p == b` true, to see why this works "unexpectedly" let's *choose some values such that the expression `p == b` is false*<sup>2</sup> yet `p < b` is true and `p > b - 1` is true.

Given `p = 3.2` (pipe) and `b = 3.7` (bird), as an example, then

```
   p == b
-> 3.2 == 3.7
-> false
```

but

```
   (p <= b) & (p > b - 1)
-> (3.2 <= 3.7) & (3.2 > 3.7 - 1)
-> (3.2 <= 3.7) & (3.2 > 2.7)
-> true & true
-> true
```

Instead, to detect when the bird "is crossing" the pipe, assuming that x increases to the right, consider

```c
   // The bird's head to the "right" of the pipe leading edge..
   bird_x >= pipe_x
   // ..but bird's butt is not to the "right" of the pipe trailing edge.
   // (Also note use of the &&, the logical-AND operator)
&& (bird_x - bird_width <= pipe_x + pipe_width)
```

Of course, using a non-rectangle (or forgiving overlap) collision detection would lead to less frustrating flapping!

---

<sup>1</sup> This issue occurs because there are some particular floating-point values (but there are no integer values) which can cause the observed effect.

First, reiterate the assumption that *`p` is not equal to `b`, given that the first condition does not succeed*. Let's suppose then that `p <= b` is written as `p == b || p < b` but since `p == b` is false , we can write it as `p < b` by tautology.

Since both clauses in the second condition are true (such that `true && true -> true`), we have the rules: 1) `p < b` is true, and 2) `p > b - 1` is true.

Rewriting `p < b` as `p - b < 0` and `p > b - 1` as `p - b > -1`, and then replacing `p - b` with `x` yields: `x < 0` and `x > -1`. However, there is no integer value of `x` which satisfies `-1 < x < 0`.

(In first section, where p = 3.2 and b = 3.7, x = (p - b) = 0.5 which satisfies the given constraints *when* x is *not* restricted to an integer value.)

---

<sup>2</sup> With all above aside, *it is possible for `p` and `b` to be "very close but different" floating-point values* such that there is a *non-zero* difference between them - due to rounding, they may even be displayed as the same integer value! See [How dangerous is it to compare floating point values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values?lq=1) and related questions for the cause and "odd" behavior of such when using `==`.

If this is the case then round to integer values and use an integer comparison, or; rely entirely on relational comparison such as shown in the proposed condition, or; use [epsilon comparison for "nearly equal"](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) of floating-point values.

Answer (score 0):

if you choose abs(pipe.position.x) == abs(bird.position.x) the first condition may satisfy.