# _wtof accuracy isn't all zeros even when string is one decimal accuracy

Tags: c, type-conversion

I'm not getting one significant digit to the right of the decimal when using _wtof. Here is my code:

```
DOUBLE fVersion = 0.0;  // Initialize to zero; confirmed fVersion is 0.00000000000000000    
TCHAR sVersion[64] = {0};
_tcscpy_s(sVersion,64,L"1.1");
fVersion = _wtof(sVersion);
```

fVersion is 1.1000000000000001 after _wtof is used, not 1.1.

Can anyone shed some light on why? But most importantly, how to fix so it's just 1.1?

Comment: floating point numbers are normally not 100% accurate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values/10335601#10335601

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accurately represent 1/10 (decimal) in binary floating point. Thus, there will be an error.

Consider representing 1/3 in decimal floating point, you end up with 0.3333333... and it just goes on forever, because it's not possible, either.

The typical recommended reading is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It's really very good, give it a read.

Comment: I'm not talking about repeating decimals, just a single precision decimal.

Comment: @JeffR: 0.1 decimal is 0.00011001100110011... in binary. Read the link unwind provided.