# Why float data type doesn't work in this code without type casting 4.7?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    float c;

    c = 4.7;

    if(c == 4.7)

    {
        printf("Hello World");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is with the float data type... To print Hello world we need to write (float)4.7 why??

Comment: because floating point representation of a number is imprecise. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: [How dangerous is it to compare floating point values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values)

Comment: You will want to read [**The Floating-Point Guide - What Every Programmer Should Know ...**](http://floating-point-gui.de/). The problem is you are not comparing what you think you are.

Comment: Only those float values which have an exact binary representation can be compared, for eg : if you do 2.5 == 2.5.

Answer (score 4):

`4.7` has the type `double`, and `c` has the type `float`. If you compare a `float` and a `double`, the `float` first gets converted to a `double`. So your `if` is doing: `(double)(float)4.7 == 4.7`, which is false, because when converting `4.7` to `float` there was a loss of precision, and the number changed a tiny bit.

You can do an approximate comparison like this `if (fabs(f - 4.7) < 1e-10)`.

Comment: Also, OP should know: compiler probably represents `4.7` as `4.699999...`. That's why `(float)4.7 != (double)4.7`. But compiler  can precisely represent some other numbers, like `1`. And OP's program can work without typecasting with these numbers.

Comment: `if (f == 4.7f)` works correctly.

Comment: Yes. Of course `4.7f == 4.7f`, because they have the same precision.

Comment: "4.7 as 4.699999..." -- those have exactly the same value (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TINfzxSnnIE). What you really mean to say is that the the binary representation of 4.7 is actually slightly smaller than 4.7 .