# In C, why is the ratio 10.0/100 different from 0.1?

Tags: c, math, conditional-statements

This is a simple question and I searched the forums, but couldn't find an answer (I found one about Log but I don't think there is a rounding error here).

I wrote a program to determine the value of a fine for a range of expired products, but when the ratio is exact, the program will return the next fine category, ignoring the = sign in the conditional.

The program must return the following fines:

- 0 if no product is expired.
- 100 if up to 10% of products are expired.
- 10000 if more than 10% of products and up to 30% are expired.
- 100000 if more than 30% of products are expired.

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int calculate_fine(int ncheckedproducts, int nexpiredproducts)
{
    int fine;
    float ratio;
    ratio=(float)nexpiredproducts/ncheckedproducts;

    if(nexpiredproducts==0)
        fine=0;
    else

        if(ratio<=0.1)
            fine=100;
        else

            if(ratio<=0.3)
                fine=10000;
            else
                fine=100000;

    return fine;
}

int main(void)
{
    int ncheckedproducts, nexpiredproducts, fine;
    printf("Type number of checked and expired products\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &ncheckedproducts, &nexpiredproducts);
    fine=calculate_fine(ncheckedproducts, nexpiredproducts);
    printf("The fine is: %d\n", fine);
    return 0;
}
```

But for values of 100 and 10, and 100 and 30, exactly 10% and 30% of expired products respectively, the program will return the wrong fine.

The teacher failed to explain me why, and corrected me to the following function:

```
int calculate_fine(int ncheckedproducts, int nexpiredproducts)
{
    int fine;

    if(nexpiredproducts==0)
        fine=0;
    else

        if(nexpiredproducts<=0.1*ncheckedproducts)
            fine=100;
        else

            if(nexpiredproducts<=0.3*ncheckedproducts)
                fine=10000;
            else
                fine=100000;

    return fine;
}
```

However, I wish to know why the first 10% ratio is greater than 0.1, and why I cannot use this approach.

Comment: um, your title is missing the crucial word!

Comment: Presumably "In pure C, why is 10/100 different from `\0`"?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Sorry for the Title problem. Fixed.

Comment: hint: Add a `printf("%.30f", ratio);` after `ratio` is assigned, and look at the value it contains (or step through with a debugger and watch `ratio`.

Comment: Never compare floats/doubles for equality. Instead of `x <= 0.3`, try `x < 0.3 + FLT_EPSILON` (or just 0.300001 to be simpler).

Comment: "ration" is not the same as "ratio". I edited the title anyway.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Your advice is not valid. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values/10335601#10335601

Comment: I realize the epsilon isn't magnitude-relative, but should work in this case where things are pretty near 1. The 0.300001 would probably be better.

Answer (score 1):

This most probably *is* a rounding issue, but a different than you might think: Many finite decimal fractions do not have a finite binary fraction representation. Thus, some rounding the the closest number representable as a floating point number of the given type happens.

Answer (score 1):

What you're dealing with is are the fine-grained aspects of floating point numbers:

Computers save floating point numbers in a binary format. Your float is probably a [IEEE-754 single precision floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

In those formats, you can typically represent only numbers exactly that are only a sum of a very limited amount of powers of two; for example, 0.75 is 2<sup>-1</sup> + 2<sup>-2</sup> and can hence be exactly reconstructed. In your case, you try to divide 100 = 2<sup>6</sup> + 2<sup>5</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> by 3 = 2<sup>1</sup>+2<sup>0</sup> and hope you get exactly the same result as 0.3 = 2<sup>-2</sup>+ 2<sup>-5</sup>+ 2<sup>-9</sup>+ 2<sup>-10</sup>+ 2<sup>-13</sup>+ ...

That won't happen.

Comment: Thank-you. I multiplied the ratio by 100 before, and changed the variable from float to integer. Now there is no rounding error to deal with.

I wish Xcode would warn of such things...

Comment: Suggest 754, not 755.  "single precision" is not specific enough as there are both binary and decimal single precision 754 formats.  Certain you want [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32)

Comment: @chux: you're right, I fixed that typo. I did not want to be so specific, because it really makes sense to read the introduction to that wikipedia page for OP.