# Perform binary trees search based a collection of data

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I was asked to write a BTS code for a collection of data with have the x, y and z coordinate, which has negative and positive number, and the requirement are below:

- That program is capable to perform binary trees search based a collection of data.
- Please use the data provided within this email. It is collection of coordinates in X,Y, and Z
- That program must capable of:
- FInding positive X, negative X, positive y, negative y, positive z, negative z.
- User can search all positive numbers, all negative numbers, etc.

So the user will input a X coordinate, it will display the Y and Z together in the output, and another is when user want to search for all Positive/Negative of X, it will also show the Y and Z with the X.
So far as I only know binary search only can perform a search on a single number, but not for a string of element with 3 numbers inside.

This is the few of the collection of X, Y and Z data for example:

```
-0.090729 0.122568 0.030209 <--- one line of X Y Z coordinate

-0.179660 0.154953 0.033881

-0.335793 0.244996 0.269589

0.075957 0.149626 0.114472
```

also I will going to use this code as the base

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int binary_search(int array[],int first,int last, int value);

int main() {

int list[10];

 for (int k=0; k<11; k++)
 list[k]=2*k+1;

 cout<< "binary search results: "<< binary_search(list,1,21,11)<<endl;

 return 0;
}//end of main
int binary_search(int array[],int first,int last, int search_key)
{
 int index;

 if (first > last)
 index = -1;

 else
 {
 int mid = (first + last)/2;

 if (search_key == array[mid])
 index = mid;
 else

 if (search_key < array[mid])
 index = binary_search(array,first, mid-1, search_key);
 else
 index = binary_search(array, mid+1, last, search_key);

 } // end if
 return index;
 }// end binarySearch
```

I was also thinking that Using array is not enough for this, and I will have to make a separate file like a database that user can search the data with one input. 
So I'm having an idea that I only do the binary tree for X coordinate but when the user input the X, it will show the Y and Z with the X from the data collection, also the data collection is a lot, any expert's help will be appreciated :) still wondering does binary search tree able to do that or not....

So this is the collections of data I need to used, can someone please tell me how to make that function that able to call the data from this huge collection?

```
0.075957 0.149626 0.114472 
0.000905 0.131220 0.031000 
0.334059 -0.004790 0.207368 
0.380561 -0.016845 0.110792 
-0.083847 -0.009495 0.260374 
0.316664 0.071467 0.120474 
-0.307909 0.341245 -0.115581 
0.411077 -0.098945 0.029724 
-0.093728 0.413972 -0.045792 
-0.445182 0.173948 0.306924 
-0.339452 0.094466 0.338246 
0.154974 0.153764 0.113986 
0.383043 -0.017294 0.038540 
0.371618 -0.036996 -0.034430 
-0.488796 0.174331 0.109211 
-0.425485 -0.003917 0.201166 
-0.328634 0.319858 0.114390 
-0.410262 0.298180 0.193996 
0.155009 0.097454 0.225033 
-0.225622 0.246139 0.118317 
-0.399749 0.163849 0.335552 
0.076578 0.133341 0.177679 
-0.201047 0.142376 0.174390 
-0.429153 -0.098775 -0.040573 
0.230882 0.131755 0.118676 
-0.483743 0.082920 0.040329 
-0.078715 0.471042 -0.055900 
-0.411718 0.237937 0.278383 
-0.005249 0.003769 0.270521 
-0.018101 0.489653 -0.124951 
-0.133572 0.398057 -0.090000 
0.154095 0.134174 0.180583 
-0.172136 0.147088 0.112057 
0.240332 0.079992 0.210373 
-0.175250 0.391765 0.011504 
-0.477955 0.162864 0.042821 
-0.263429 0.246060 0.204495 
0.408153 -0.094551 0.112774 
0.388142 -0.103007 0.184936 
-0.257106 0.309349 0.107726 
-0.020619 0.343770 -0.051245 
-0.366778 -0.278556 0.116261 
-0.329815 0.313916 0.034602 
-0.482418 0.071724 0.268572 
0.296142 0.067455 0.185325 
0.392588 -0.106540 -0.040632 
-0.348415 0.380318 -0.132477 
0.074743 0.098941 0.226089 
0.313984 -0.095701 0.274736 
-0.000127 0.359321 -0.099978 
-0.389304 0.419894 -0.275472 
-0.448952 -0.015681 0.018614 
0.360441 0.017741 0.133138 
0.072016 -0.429793 0.306404 
0.157903 -0.423369 0.305657 
-0.253995 0.329448 0.039563 
-0.486770 0.073079 0.193422 
-0.277697 0.136104 0.260296 
-0.000924 0.131167 0.114723 
-0.324768 0.304498 0.200203 
-0.172816 0.407647 -0.040188 
-0.262926 -0.426393 0.279458 
-0.389169 0.326903 -0.115444 
-0.171523 0.319164 0.036876 
-0.166670 -0.433521 0.278390 
-0.052386 -0.126211 0.329163 
0.021908 0.122344 0.172256 
-0.467692 -0.118237 0.042218 
-0.339549 0.330551 -0.049267 
-0.333589 0.232102 -0.053896 
0.240226 -0.009687 0.271713 
-0.125529 0.419457 -0.000220 
-0.323461 0.062386 -0.069065 
-0.335525 0.413992 -0.292639 
-0.485317 0.253072 0.122003 
0.160470 0.053417 0.252663 
0.320594 -0.097082 -0.121452 
0.153275 -0.012350 0.284012 
-0.351329 0.151160 0.328284 
0.155106 0.152666 0.034476 
0.237370 -0.432505 0.276914 
0.213352 -0.110928 0.333017 
0.076081 0.050562 0.261882 
-0.420589 0.067501 -0.027579 
-0.404542 0.241335 -0.029536 
0.154083 -0.010130 -0.141933 
-0.011780 0.079933 0.212997 
0.076419 0.148417 0.035528 
-0.474790 0.231229 0.188058 
0.065221 0.102536 -0.068695 
-0.341908 0.470328 -0.362529 
-0.081834 0.109006 0.134754 
-0.445012 0.272483 0.212757 
-0.471614 -0.110944 0.114503 
-0.086541 0.096661 -0.045842 
-0.087413 0.067613 0.198527 
-0.400299 0.085220 0.335886 
0.335514 0.004886 -0.052942 
-0.331894 -0.098257 -0.115394 
-0.384468 -0.109560 -0.094346 
-0.429120 -0.083583 0.201641 
-0.450774 0.192619 0.008875 
-0.077900 -0.436097 0.335867 
-0.001575 -0.432054 0.337764 
-0.318593 0.418017 -0.378191 
-0.081679 0.417342 -0.113276 
-0.256147 0.180127 0.214579 
-0.324634 0.166962 0.291635 
-0.165520 0.315139 -0.053349 
-0.244783 -0.239901 0.258588 
-0.157444 -0.112794 -0.153111 
0.001362 -0.102979 0.350567 
0.076088 -0.090730 0.354817 
0.395664 -0.267686 0.191676 
0.304469 0.060476 -0.029716 
-0.103680 -0.414289 0.294346 
-0.240880 0.071427 0.229963 
0.395003 -0.186405 -0.042120 
0.312090 -0.430972 0.197739 
-0.092992 -0.078157 -0.160328 
0.367958 -0.017433 0.172606 
-0.072734 -0.114118 -0.196052 
0.001156 -0.422750 0.282151 
0.140519 -0.396572 0.327980 
0.401578 -0.409301 0.180077 
-0.038587 0.485641 -0.078435 
0.078437 -0.338751 0.352289 
0.150609 -0.344197 0.348366 
-0.468113 -0.013229 0.110504 
-0.258706 -0.401441 0.198291 
-0.080173 -0.353192 0.259849 
0.076135 -0.012304 0.287421 
-0.025898 -0.350688 0.291216 
0.008889 -0.332588 0.332609 
-0.259982 0.255333 -0.021288 
-0.500000 0.074738 0.115107 
-0.293236 0.334808 -0.197488 
-0.450030 -0.006072 0.139787 
0.338110 -0.354940 0.228053 
0.398298 -0.341848 0.204755 
-0.171607 0.062339 0.205716 
-0.334439 0.323599 -0.285487 
0.295641 -0.030420 0.258598 
-0.078645 0.467777 -0.100027 
-0.388458 -0.109277 0.249584 
-0.010804 -0.060563 0.298001 
-0.235267 -0.337188 0.190461 
-0.169882 -0.344871 0.254487 
-0.434959 0.052108 0.305670 
0.211018 0.127704 0.169978 
-0.141419 0.105761 0.161259 
-0.277201 0.080277 0.260381 
-0.348562 0.307347 -0.210293 
-0.264058 0.296204 0.184212 
-0.201645 -0.339661 0.235866 
0.044728 0.475219 -0.187208 
-0.467501 -0.011187 0.052141 
-0.406464 0.305509 0.039260 
-0.079797 0.121035 0.092894 
-0.424583 0.308193 0.113378 
-0.410118 -0.023560 -0.044817 
-0.048690 0.100157 0.158385 
-0.323503 0.344986 -0.356561 
-0.403118 -0.246061 0.111481 
0.051702 0.432676 -0.178928 
-0.258646 -0.350652 0.045387 
-0.005999 0.095570 -0.055052 
-0.344346 0.255465 -0.122999 
-0.157020 0.102027 -0.067144 
-0.337089 0.267242 -0.193677 
-0.241299 -0.345101 0.113604 
0.003790 -0.261338 0.347452 
0.075487 -0.264686 0.369264 
0.162459 -0.267253 0.361906 
0.020993 0.060885 0.246241 
0.471800 -0.343702 0.172142 
0.149844 -0.096394 0.350343 
-0.169260 -0.266480 0.265656 
-0.078075 -0.262286 0.267258 
-0.135235 0.358184 -0.088433 
-0.255263 -0.279737 0.222196 
-0.387804 0.315919 -0.042996 
-0.249325 0.097467 -0.066377 
0.232603 -0.011736 -0.126844 
0.468932 -0.278385 0.170881 
-0.458816 -0.088186 0.015550 
-0.389489 0.356552 -0.200456 
-0.175817 0.130162 -0.025492 
-0.091194 -0.184586 0.283638 
-0.247519 -0.009323 -0.126505 
-0.362708 0.015190 -0.066164 
-0.250302 -0.104264 -0.143793 
-0.206967 -0.275905 0.243332 
-0.197050 0.247164 0.041679 
-0.415699 0.144577 -0.034869 
-0.160657 -0.012060 -0.135141 
0.073840 -0.096450 -0.221220 
0.076158 -0.010711 -0.150732 
-0.079237 0.333988 -0.044751 
-0.001993 -0.009713 -0.147751 
-0.469462 0.198805 0.256553 
-0.330455 0.136368 -0.060891 
0.422080 -0.239554 0.139433 
-0.155069 0.062187 -0.100190 
0.045128 0.395109 -0.135353 
-0.236349 0.328456 -0.022454 
0.150712 -0.095474 -0.203321 
-0.395556 -0.231558 0.172341 
-0.297510 0.278742 -0.103171 
-0.339099 -0.258986 0.198846 
-0.244746 -0.177858 -0.137134 
-0.173047 -0.190625 0.279613 
-0.007145 -0.190266 0.364539 
0.075964 -0.187064 0.378191 
0.162311 -0.175585 0.365091 
-0.446336 0.252967 0.034904 
0.360230 0.017437 0.013711 
-0.335841 -0.181269 0.265241 
-0.253792 -0.188356 0.283896 
0.367728 -0.129890 -0.095475 
-0.309241 -0.450194 0.258058 
-0.346159 0.401686 -0.210900 
-0.292800 0.317122 -0.141242 
-0.296030 0.360867 -0.265735 
-0.338339 -0.101703 0.275068 
-0.210562 0.208448 0.093963 
-0.402655 0.015646 0.272364 
0.234197 -0.188255 0.339100 
0.150828 0.105100 -0.069723 
-0.252361 -0.094102 0.288347 
-0.169846 -0.103389 0.282147 
-0.081747 -0.090851 0.290155 
0.251737 -0.136450 0.321562 
0.229362 0.131550 0.030055 
-0.076129 -0.006871 -0.140948 
0.238180 -0.085572 0.311821 
0.076712 0.058579 -0.109601 
-0.233470 0.362778 0.015787 
0.352277 -0.078644 -0.083349 
-0.487177 0.156348 0.191350 
-0.332970 -0.005332 0.263005 
-0.176265 -0.018775 0.261670 
0.165160 -0.062183 0.318872 
-0.251163 -0.025516 0.268080 
-0.326562 0.052598 0.309106 
-0.215845 0.215242 0.013283 
-0.250863 0.162990 -0.035906 
0.018121 0.489990 -0.177498 
-0.079734 0.357054 -0.098577 
-0.255718 0.023253 0.243169 
-0.155250 0.018091 0.241299 
-0.095910 0.017906 0.241005 
0.280869 0.018851 0.239697 
-0.194925 0.262219 -0.018530 
-0.005598 -0.479311 0.331880 
-0.002292 0.414560 -0.123543 
-0.260753 -0.481258 0.276218 
0.154172 -0.480161 0.274365 
-0.167268 -0.479832 0.271694 
-0.323638 -0.019706 -0.102023 
0.285772 -0.408742 0.248108 
0.366403 -0.172115 -0.097373 
-0.442366 -0.184972 0.119327 
0.467558 -0.397663 0.116399 
0.238829 -0.357919 0.301619 
0.164031 0.069292 -0.104950 
-0.092374 0.325879 0.002629 
0.304791 -0.336291 0.265589 
0.500000 -0.348679 0.115310 
0.227075 -0.117799 -0.181677 
0.211965 -0.325049 0.327752 
0.358338 -0.105352 0.238236 
-0.015772 0.387595 -0.078307 
0.214950 -0.264517 0.340296 
0.254757 -0.262003 0.316288 
0.313084 -0.262813 0.273214 
0.359071 -0.263765 0.238343 
0.495477 -0.261305 0.109474 
0.325024 -0.193317 -0.130771 
-0.386855 0.449060 -0.338864 
-0.317542 -0.310432 0.112304 
-0.417095 -0.173898 0.198758 
0.241026 0.090858 -0.049727 
0.318413 -0.186461 0.281366 
0.361404 -0.188428 0.239352 
0.392783 -0.186163 0.191749 
0.419850 -0.187629 0.113618 
-0.405129 -0.244415 0.041488 
-0.078681 0.053919 -0.101020 
-0.459326 0.038064 0.023302 
0.021646 0.437884 -0.175533 
0.231143 -0.479464 -0.043005 
0.222780 -0.475271 -0.110977 
0.243339 -0.475372 0.203179 
0.403476 -0.440490 0.034505 
0.265111 -0.443827 -0.056269 
0.242083 -0.429440 -0.130781 
0.389655 -0.410616 -0.027253 
0.404388 -0.439917 0.113291 
0.454583 -0.405555 0.034545 
0.304492 -0.017036 -0.097924 
0.318352 -0.418003 -0.044667 
-0.006068 -0.085607 -0.207010 
-0.092889 -0.485483 -0.191576 
0.287708 -0.397662 -0.113398 
0.481895 -0.258555 0.035148 
0.459541 -0.348207 -0.020224 
0.490604 -0.353829 0.030048 
0.398522 -0.346518 -0.043788 
-0.294172 0.394323 -0.352233 
0.341075 -0.354125 -0.066500 
0.310707 -0.341708 -0.120061 
-0.001949 0.053880 -0.108140 
-0.160536 -0.475848 -0.178375 
0.081321 -0.427695 -0.184472 
-0.323267 -0.485070 -0.031361 
0.429826 -0.241506 0.032040 
0.280277 -0.166830 -0.166326 
-0.082011 -0.430622 -0.190980 
0.259778 -0.371250 -0.160124 
-0.063844 -0.479809 0.332759 
0.222145 0.052023 -0.099953 
0.325379 -0.262782 -0.125122 
0.392030 -0.265942 -0.040276 
0.455904 -0.291006 -0.015375 
-0.474778 0.135820 0.279064 
0.419232 -0.185902 0.034486 
-0.350612 0.278498 -0.259807 
-0.168321 -0.427839 -0.120334 
-0.360026 0.463230 -0.317495 
-0.387025 0.461928 -0.315415 
0.316651 0.070958 0.034101 
-0.394244 0.396200 -0.201302 
0.249565 -0.098461 -0.160699 
-0.052792 -0.184322 0.333604 
-0.314333 -0.478718 0.103402 
-0.312439 -0.480349 0.190804 
-0.310186 -0.438183 0.197410 
-0.309481 -0.479378 0.252555 
-0.331159 -0.487284 0.035204 
-0.333495 -0.435541 0.040352 
-0.263413 -0.426976 0.128511 
-0.303818 -0.438361 0.090061 
-0.277050 -0.400649 0.037718 
-0.038925 -0.278358 0.294233 
-0.304313 -0.238548 0.246970 
-0.011962 -0.176767 -0.257824 
-0.166728 -0.485130 -0.130257 
0.070000 -0.483251 -0.137440 
-0.318461 -0.442320 -0.030378 
-0.138111 -0.435125 -0.178330 
-0.252236 -0.426105 -0.053975 
-0.159840 -0.434426 -0.069893 
-0.097390 -0.417033 -0.114525 
-0.087536 -0.339895 -0.126204 
-0.167931 -0.340827 -0.078534 
-0.248072 -0.337747 -0.038942 
-0.057447 -0.336240 -0.190659 
-0.249331 0.064124 -0.092216 
-0.010390 -0.350874 -0.214420 
-0.338845 -0.258346 -0.047109 
-0.367182 -0.279822 0.032717 
-0.021345 -0.267534 -0.245406 
-0.076570 -0.266564 -0.195832 
-0.101198 -0.272924 -0.132843 
-0.001765 -0.485288 -0.175093 
-0.395722 -0.228026 -0.030905 
0.215824 0.121247 -0.021429 
-0.443022 -0.183083 0.031252 
-0.408828 -0.184413 -0.046159 
-0.089085 -0.186963 -0.210342 
-0.119101 -0.171558 -0.153775 
-0.334735 -0.182650 -0.112396 
-0.223385 -0.485981 -0.089089 
0.222636 -0.180295 -0.196924 
0.020131 -0.131068 -0.255166 
0.001177 -0.426232 -0.190799 
-0.012155 -0.064992 -0.167676 
-0.251505 -0.489586 -0.044734 
0.162056 -0.065542 -0.166444 
0.017214 0.121009 -0.020486 
0.231414 -0.347292 -0.184091 
0.052590 -0.187358 -0.254877 
0.150268 -0.453553 -0.148873 
0.231710 -0.263207 -0.195083 
0.077347 0.134286 -0.022666 
0.157028 0.134088 -0.024777 
0.152628 -0.483117 -0.122336 
0.312729 -0.474830 0.028494 
0.156938 -0.408421 -0.178160 
0.210296 -0.399260 -0.170051 
0.155543 -0.345337 -0.204948 
0.075077 -0.351087 -0.219512 
-0.113516 -0.334652 -0.079797 
0.070376 -0.262941 -0.241359 
0.152999 -0.265258 -0.221395 
-0.260925 -0.281522 -0.067153 
-0.163813 -0.249589 -0.110536 
-0.000517 -0.245935 -0.256464 
-0.251757 -0.234363 -0.110374 
-0.305968 -0.241161 -0.095382 
0.153196 -0.189709 -0.227997 
0.093251 -0.180480 -0.246527 
-0.048941 -0.173545 -0.249073 
-0.157017 -0.189159 -0.134516 
-0.370694 -0.198645 -0.084469 
-0.003756 -0.479136 -0.132966 
-0.093078 -0.475263 -0.122568 
0.075829 -0.460227 -0.099777 
-0.001899 -0.459362 -0.105936 
0.165415 -0.477174 -0.046786 
0.144067 -0.458390 -0.051246 
0.076365 -0.454779 -0.042957 
-0.000796 -0.457043 -0.042454 
-0.168778 -0.486562 -0.041229 
0.240678 -0.480161 0.029208 
-0.082080 -0.458459 -0.042333 
0.149462 -0.481931 0.033089 
0.122461 -0.463743 0.002471 
0.076974 -0.458785 0.035224 
-0.165019 -0.485403 0.035211 
-0.002507 -0.458952 0.035797 
0.305050 -0.475313 0.120096 
-0.248056 -0.489990 0.034763 
-0.072565 -0.460061 0.025380 
0.109360 -0.475999 0.064561 
0.243323 -0.479673 0.126123 
-0.110629 -0.489074 0.043599 
0.151045 -0.483545 0.115056 
0.113069 -0.479908 0.084853 
0.336442 -0.463570 0.135023 
0.076638 -0.459867 0.113200 
-0.117317 -0.480495 0.113990 
-0.002076 -0.459748 0.113895 
-0.057473 -0.462636 0.113188 
-0.256639 -0.489621 0.112012 
0.123161 -0.463285 0.143835 
0.181877 -0.477548 0.192178 
0.151977 -0.457373 0.192210 
0.076190 -0.455132 0.193957 
-0.102975 -0.477424 0.189320 
-0.067928 -0.459351 0.209563 
-0.002745 -0.457144 0.191918 
-0.161571 -0.485037 0.194232 
0.216362 -0.476830 0.268931 
-0.250727 -0.485793 0.193098 
-0.320925 -0.308279 0.034877 
0.072334 -0.480626 0.296205 
-0.087828 -0.482461 0.282326 
-0.003897 -0.482100 0.299386
```

does this code will work if i place all the data into a data.txt file and read it in the main.cpp?

```
int main ()
{
    {

    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("Data.txt");
    char output[100];
     if (myReadFile.is_open()) 
     {
     while (!myReadFile.eof()) 
        {
            myReadFile >> output;
            cout<<output;
        }
     }
    myReadFile.close();
    return 0;
    }
```

and this is the bubble sort for the vertex X, I know it will take a really long time to sort it, but time doesn't matter as long as the code works.

```
for (i=0; i<500-1; i++)
        for (int j=i+1; j<500; j++)
            if (X[i] > X[j])
            {
                int temp = X[i];
                X[i] = X [j];
                X[j] = temp;
                temp = Y[i];
                Y[i] = Y [j];
                Y[j] = temp;
                temp = Z[i];
                Z[i] = Z [j];
                Z[j] = temp;
            }
```

Comment: Hi, here some thoughts: 1) you have to sort your input collection before performing bst. 2) recrusion may end with an stackoverflow, better use loops 3) why not using a sqlite database ?

Answer (score 1):

You talk about [binary search trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) but the code you have shown does a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on a sorted array. That is not the same thing.

One way of using your binary search would be to put the X,Y and Z values together in an array or custom struct. Something like:

```
struct Vertex {
  float X;
  float Y;
  float Z;
};
```

Modify your binary search function so that it takes an array of these structs instead of an array of integers. You will have to make your search key an X float value:

```
int binary_search(Vertex array[],int first,int last, float x_value);
```

Load your X, Y, Z values into an array of `Vertex` and then sort by X value:

```
bool vertexXComparator(const Vertex& lhs, const Vertex& rhs) {
  return lhs.X < rhs.X;
}

std::sort(list, list+number_of_vertexes, vertexXComparator);
```

Then you should be able to use your binary search (or std::binary_search) on the sorted list.

I would be a bit wary of using a float as a search key. [It is generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values) to test floating point numbers for equality.

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uCUiAVzmurml4jR2).