# compare double values in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to compare two double values in swift

```
var first_value = 10.20
var second_value = 20.30
if first_value > second_value
   println("some statement")
```

how can we compare this type of stuff..

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you learn in Swift is {} are mandatory for all if, if else, and else statements.

So, your code should look like this:

```
 var first_value = 10.20
 var second_value = 20.30

 if first_value > second_value {
     print("first_value is greater than second_value")
 }
 else {
     print("first_value is not greater than second_value ")
 }
```

Comment: This is at best a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should'n use '>', '<' and '=' signs to compare float or double.
Especially for comparison of close values (float i = 0.56; float j = 0.56; time to time you'll get wrong results in comparison i == j).
You should use constants from float.h, as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values).

Answer (score 1):

Comparing 2 double numbers using binary signs <,>, == is not entirely correct because of the device of this type of data in the computer's memory. For example, compare 2 double values:

```
var a: Double = 10.0
var b: Double = 10.0
print(a == b) // false
```

So, you need determine decimal place precision for comparison.

```
public extension Double {
    func greaterThan(_ value: Double, precise: Int) -> Bool {
        let denominator: Double = pow(10.0, Double(precise))
        let maxDiff: Double = 1 / denominator
        let realDiff: Double = self - value

        if fabs(realDiff) >= maxDiff, realDiff > 0 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func greaterThanOrEqual(_ value: Double, precise: Int) -> Bool {
        let denominator: Double = pow(10.0, Double(precise))
        let maxDiff: Double = 1 / denominator
        let realDiff: Double = self - value

        if fabs(realDiff) >= maxDiff, realDiff >= 0 {
            return true
        } else if fabs(realDiff) <= maxDiff {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func lessThan(_ value: Double, precise: Int) -> Bool {
        let denominator: Double = pow(10.0, Double(precise))
        let maxDiff: Double = 1 / denominator
        let realDiff: Double = self - value

        if fabs(realDiff) >= maxDiff, realDiff < 0 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func lessThanOrEqual(_ value: Double, precise: Int) -> Bool {
        let denominator: Double = pow(10.0, Double(precise))
        let maxDiff: Double = 1 / denominator
        let realDiff: Double = self - value

        if fabs(realDiff) >= maxDiff, realDiff <= 0 {
            return true
        } else if fabs(realDiff) <= maxDiff {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func equal(_ value: Double, precise: Int) -> Bool {
        let denominator: Double = pow(10.0, Double(precise))
        let maxDiff: Double = 1 / denominator
        let realDiff: Double = self - value

        if fabs(realDiff) <= maxDiff {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var a: Double = 10.0
var b: Double = 10.0
print(a.equal(a, precise: 3)) // true
```

Comment: Why you have write 3 as Precise ? what is meaning of that ? precise: 3

Answer (score 0):

Updated Ans

```
        var first_value = 10.20
        var second_value = 20.30

        if first_value.isLess(than: second_value) {
            print("first_value is not greater than second_value ")
        } else {
            print("first_value is greater than second_value ")
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Please read intro chapters to basic swift syntax:

```
var first_value = 10.20
var second_value = 20.30
if first_value > second_value {
    println("some statement")
}
```