# If Statement Not Running When Condition is True

Tags: swift, if-statement, sprite-kit

In this code, one of my sprites should reduce speed until it meets 0.75. However, once the code does get to 0.75, it keeps reducing for some reason. *I have a timer which calls the speed_Control func every 0.2 seconds and the sprite.speed starts at 1.0.*

```
func speed_Control() {
    if boolDecrease == true {
        speed_Decrease()
    }
}

func speed_Decrease() {
    if sprite.speed != 0.75 {
        println(sprite.speed)
        sprite.speed -= 0.05
    } else {
        boolDecrease = false
    }
}
```

I added println(sprite.speed) to see if my sprite does actually ever return 0.75, which it does, so I don't know how it passes if sprite.speed != 0.75.

Can anybody see what is wrong with this?

Comment: You should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values

Comment: Thanks for the link, this has given me a better understanding why floats are not exact. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating-point values should not be compared using (in)equality operators. The value `0.05` cannot be exactly represented, so `speed` will end up being something close to, but not exactly equal to `0.75`. A simple solution here would be to change the condition `sprite.speed != 0.75` to `sprite.speed > 0.76`.

Comment: Thanks feersum. I will use > instead.