# why is numeric_limits<T>::min being interpreted as a function pointer by compiler?

Tags: c++, g++

I was writing a floating point comparison function using templates:

```
template<class T>
    static bool AlmostEqual(T f1, T f2)
```

I had a statement such as:

```
T min_value = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
```

For some reason the compiler treats the min above as a function pointer and issues the error:

```
   ../include/CommonFunctions.h: In static member function ‘static bool CommonFunctions::AlmostEqual(T, T) [with T = double]’:
file.cpp:2200:   instantiated from here
../include/CommonFunctions.h:22: error: cannot convert ‘double (*)()throw ()’ to ‘double’ in initialization
```

The static function is defined as part of a big program. But, when I put the same function in a standalone file and compile and use it, I see no error. I read other posts and tried something like this:

```
T min_value(std::numeric_limits<T>::min());
```

I still get the same error and also one more:

```
../include/CommonFunctions.h:22:53: error: macro "min" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
```

In one error, it is able to resolve the min as a function correctly and in another error it is being treated as a macro. I'm not sure, how to resolve this issue. Any pointers would be appreciated?

Comment: Post the complete code please.

Comment: And say `#undef min` after you included all your private headers.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/RhsuQX)

Comment: Kerrek SB - Using #undef min helped solved the issue. Please post it as an answer with explanation, I will mark it accepted. Complete function is similar to the one here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10335601/768469

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For people including windows.h, put the following in effected headers:

```
#include windows headers ...

pragma push_macro("min")
pragma push_macro("max")
#undef min
#undef max

#include headers expecting std::min/std::max ...

...

pragma pop_macro("min")
pragma pop_macro("max")
```

In source files just #undef min and max.

```
#include windows headers ...

#undef min
#undef max

#include headers expecting std::min/std::max ...
```