# Why this comparison to zero is not working properly?

Tags: c++, c++11, double

I have this code:

```
double A = doSomethingWonderful(); // same as doing  A = 0;
if(A == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"A=%llx\n", A);
}
```

and this output:

```
A=7f35959a51c0
```

how is this possible?

I checked the value of 7f35959a51c0 and seems to be something like 6.91040329973658785751176861252E-310, which is very small, but not zero.

EDIT:

Ok I understood that that way of printing the hex value for a double is not working. I need to find a way to print the bytes of the double.

Following the comments I modified my code:

```
    A = doSomethingWonderful();// same as doing  A = 0;
    if(A == 0)
    {
        char bytes[8];
        memcpy(bytes, &A, sizeof(double));
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        fprintf(stderr," %x", bytes[i]);
    }
```

and I get this output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So finally it seems that the comparison is working properly but I was doing a bad print.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How dangerous is it to compare floating point values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values)

Comment: @HadeS is not a duplicate, I perfectly know that is dangerous. :)

Comment: Did you mean to use %llx and not %f to print the value?  AFAIK using %llx to print a double is undefined behavior.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: the point is that zero in hex is 0x0000000000000000. I want to trigger this value and only this value. The printf should only print 0x0000000000000000 in any possible case. If A has non zero bits, it shouldn't even go in the branch.

Comment: Dunno about the language-lawyer aspect, but as a quick work-around, if (memcmp(&A, 0, sizeof(A))==0) would do the trick.   Btw IIRC there may be double values that mean zero but are not all zero-bits.

Comment: @HAL9000 Nonetheless printing a double value with llx is undefined. You can convert it manually to an 8byte integer first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IEEE 754 precision floating point values use a bias in the exponent value in order to fully represent both positive and negative exponents. For double-precision values, that bias is 1023<sup>[[source]](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html)</sup>, which happens to be `0x3ff` in hex, which matches the hex value of `A` that you printed for `1`, or `0e0`.

---

Two other small notes:

- When printing bytes, you can use `%hhx` to get it to only print 2 hex digits instead of sign-extending to 8.
- You can use a union to reliably print the double value as an 8-byte integer.

```
double A = 0;
if(A == 0)
{
    A = 1; // Note that you were setting A to 1 here!
    char bytes[8];
    memcpy(bytes, &A, sizeof(double));
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        printf(" %hhx", bytes[i]);
}
int isZero;
union {
    unsigned long i;
    double d;
} u;
u.d = 0;
isZero = (u.d == 0.0);
printf("\n============\n");
printf("hex   = %lx\nfloat = %f\nzero?   %d\n", u.i, u.d, isZero);
```

Result:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 f0 3f
============
hex   = 0
float = 0.000000
zero?   1
```

So in the first line, we see that `1.0` is `0e0` (i.e., 0<sup>0</sup>).

In the following lines, we see that when you use a union to print the hex value of the double `0.0`, you get `0` as expected.

Comment: @HAL9000 - No, you were setting `A=1`, which is `0E0`, which is what it was printing.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass your double to `printf()`, you pass it as a *floating point* value. However, since the `"%x"` format is an integer format, your `printf()` implementation will try to read an *integer* argument. Due to this fundamental type mismatch, it is possible, for instance, that the calling code places your double value in a floating point register, while the `printf()` implementation tries to read it from an integer register. Details depend on your ABI, but apparently the bits that you see are not the bits that you passed. From a language point of view, you have undefined behavior the moment that you have a type mismatch between one `printf()` argument and its corresponding format specification.

Apart from that, `+0.0` is indeed represented as all bits zero, both in single and in double precision formats. However, this is only positive zero, `-0.0` is represented with the sign bit set.

In your last bit of code, you are inspecting the bit pattern of `1.0`, because you overwrite the value of `A` before you do the conversion. Note also that you get `fffffff0` instead of `f0` for the seventh byte because of sign extension. For correct output, use an array of `unsigned` bytes.

The pattern that you are seeing decodes like this:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f
to big endian:
3f f0 00 00 00 00 00 00

decode fields:
sign: 0 (1 bit)
exponent: 01111111111 (11 bit), value = 1023
    exponent = value - bias = 1023 - 1023 = 0
mantissa: 0...0 (52 bit), value with implicit leading 1 bit: 1.0000...

entire value: -1^0 * 2^0 * 1.0 = 1.0
```