# Is this algorithm to find the sum to infinity of a series acceptable?

Tags: java, c, algorithm, math

The sum to infinity of the following series is to be found:

```
1  1/2  1/3  1/4  1/5 ...
```

According to the explanation of a certain scientist, *infinity is that point beyond which any point is non existent, i.e., **inf + x = inf** or **inf ~ (inf + x) = 0***. So, based on this theory, the following algorithm was used:

```
float sum=0.0;
for(int i=0;;i++){
    if((sum+(1.0/i))==sum)
    break;
    sum+=(1.0/i);
}
/* print the value of sum */
```

The algorithm was run in **C** and **JAVA** and both gave the output as ***inf***. The print statements written in **C** and **Java** respectively are

```
printf("%6f",sum);  

System.out.println(sum);
```

---

**EDIT:**
The code written earlier (in the question) had a mistake because I typed it, didn't copy-paste. Sorry for that. That being solved, here's the code I'd base my question upon:

```
float sum=0.0;
for(int i=1;;i++){
    if((sum+ (1.0/i))==sum)
    break;
    sum+=(1.0/i);
}
/*print the value of sum*/
```

---

A friend of mine said he got the output as a finite fractional number in **C**. But in my case, the program never terminated, both in **C** and **Java***(This output was got from the new edited code posted above. Do not consider the previous faulty code and it's output which was "INF".)* My question is, is this algorithm acceptable? And if yes, then I'd like to know the possible of cause different outputs in **C**. Thanks.

Comment: You're adding 1/0 (which is infinity) in the very first iteration... change `i` to start at 1 and you'll get different results...

Comment: It will terminate when the int i overflows and becomes 0, whereby you will add 1/0 which is infinity.

Comment: @DawidPi: Don't most implementations of C use IEEE-754, which *does* have a representation of infinity? (And it's not just "Java's max double number" - it's "the IEEE-754 representation of infinity. The maximum representable finite `double` is a very different number.)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen it stops in the if statement, when i is so large, that after addidition 1.0/i to sum it does not change it's value - flot precision is too small

Comment: Actually, there's a subtlety here, at least in Java - `sum+(1.0/i) == sum` is performed using `double` arithmetic, whereas `sum += (1.0/i)` performs the addition using `double` arithmetic *but then converts the result back to `float`*. So I wouldn't be surprised if it really didn't terminate... but declaring `sum` as a `double` instead, it would (if `i` overflowing weren't an issue...)

Comment: That being said, mathematically speaking, sum of 1/n from 1 to n is tends to be proportional to the natural log of n, so within the bounds of a positive int, you're more likely to get an answer thats in the area of ln(Integer.MAX_VALUE)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I was wrong. sorry.

Comment: But still in fact what you are doing is undefined behavior in C, because of division by zero in first iteration.

Comment: I've edited the question. Please check.

Comment: I rolled the changes back You had completely changed the question.

Comment: This sum doesn't converge.

Comment: Did you even try to compile/run this code?  Whee did you get it from?

Comment: 'A friend of mine said he got the output as a finite fractional number' - what did YOU get when you tried it?

Comment: You are making this up as you go along:(

Comment: Ignoring the mistake in the code, i.e., considering I started from ´i=1´, I didn't get an output. The program didn't terminate by itself. The loop became infinite.

Comment: I ain't making anything up. I just made a small mistake in the beginning. And I donno why I cannot delete the question.

Comment: A small mistake?  How is it possible for a copy/paste from the code that you tried to change '1' to '0'?

Comment: Stephen C answered your question and got 5 upvotes for it, (well OK, he answered the edited version of your question that mentioned INF).  Why would you want him to lose those 5 upvotes by deleting your question?

Comment: Initially I wrote ´i=0´ instead of ´i=1´ which gave me the output ´inf´.

Comment: Because my reputation is being degraded on stackoverflow also.

Comment: If you cannot copy/paste code from the environment where you tested it, it's best to not ask the question.   Transcribing code by hand is notoriously error-prone and results in cockups like this one:)  Your error upon entering code diffferent than that you tested just wasted everyone's time.  Copy/paste it, or don't post.

Comment: I copy pasted it sir. I did the same mistake in the IDE as here. Kindly understand that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @Raedwald That wasn't the question and this isn't the typical "what's wrong with my code" question (those should be closed as off-topic, not as duplicates). The question is if the algorithm is correct. Now as it happened, the code had several severe bugs. But that doesn't make it a duplicate of some debugger question.

Comment: @Lundin The division by zero in the first iteration would be very obvious in a debugger. The pister has evidently nit tried to debug their code.

Comment: Anyway since the OP insists on trying to "edit-fix" all of the code, I don't think this question is salvageable.

Comment: Questions solvable by basic debugging are unwelcome: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254094/question-that-can-be-solved-using-basic-debugging

Comment: @Raedwald why are you typing like Officer Crabtree?

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik Ask a new question, this one is asked and answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The algorithm was run in C and JAVA and both gave the output as inf.

That is because there is a bug in your code.  You are starting with `i == 0`.  When you calculate `1.0 / 0` you get an INF.

The series is supposed to start with `i == 1` ...

You edited the question to fix to that particular bug.

Even so, you still will never get a correct value for the sum to infinity.  The series diverges (goes to infinity) but given the way you are calculating it, there is no way that you will get there.

Eventually, you will reach a point where `1.0/i` is too small to change `sum` and you will break out of the loop.  I expect that will happen before `i == Integer.MAX_VALUE` ... but if it didn't, then you would run into ANOTHER bug in your code.  If `i` ever reached `Integer.MAX_VALUE` then it would wrap around to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and you will start adding *negative* terms to the sum.  Oops!

---

Actually, what you are trying to calculate is the Harmonic Series.  The partial sums (for N terms) converge to log<sub>e</sub> N + E, where E is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Partial_sums

From this, one should be able to estimate when the difference between Nth partial sum and `1.0 / N` becomes large enough to stop the iteration.

A final note: you will get more accurate sums if you sum in the opposite direction; i.e. starting with very large N and summing with N reducing to 1.

Comment: Yeah that was a small mistake.

Comment: A "small mistake" which caused the result you are seeing.  If you fix it, you won't see INF's

Comment: I changed the for statement to `for(int i=1;;i++)`. Umm...the ide used for **C** is a mobile app. And I'm having a problem. It'd be nice if someone tells me the output when the loop starts from **i=1**.

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik When there are posted answers, please don't edit the question into something entirely different that invalidates the posted answers. Instead, ask a new question. If needed, post a link to this one. I'll rollback your edit now, you'll still have your question changes available in the edit history.

Comment: @Ludin I cannot delete the question. Why?

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik there are upvoted answers, eg. this one.

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik - That is correct.  People have spent time and effort answering your question.  It is no longer up to you to decide if the Question + Answers worth keeping.  This is now >>community<< property.

Comment: I think, ignoring the error, I should expect people to answer the real question.

Comment: If you read my answer properly, you will see that I do address the real question.

Comment: This error in his code would be very obvious if he had used a debugger.

Comment: @Raedwald debugger?  I suspect that the OP did not even build/test it!

Comment: @Stephen C Thanks for your explanation. Sorry I was so busy tackling the chaos that I didn't notice you'd already given an explanation. But one thing though. If it is so, as you explained in your answer about the other bug, how do you think did that other guy got the output? I was told that he got **5.17..** something like that. That was in **C**.

Comment: We need the source code for the C and Java versions to answer that.

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with your code. Your program doesn't work, it only seems to work.

- [Never compare float numbers for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values).
- Computers can't divide by zero.
- Literals `0.0` are of type `double`. Meaning that the calculation `sum+(1.0/i)` is performed on type `double`, which might be a larger type than `float` on the particular system. Your code assumes that `float` and `double` have the same representation, so it is non-portable.

  Therefore the result may not be too large during the calculation, which is done on type `double`, but it doesn't fit when you try to show it back into a `float`. Instead use `f` prefix on all literals, that is: `1.0f`. Or just use `double` consistently all over the program.
- Avoid cryptic loops. There's no need to move the loop condition inside the loop body. Your loop should look something like `for(int i=0; float_compare(sum+1.0f/i, sum); i++)`, where `float_compare` is some way to compare float numbers. Something like this:

  ```
  #include <math.h>
  #define EPSILON 0.00001f

  inline bool float_compare (float x, float y)
  {
    return fabsf(result - expectedResult) < EPSILON;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Some notes The range of i is important - integers have only fixed representations.

The series 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ... is divergent  ([wikipedia : sum of recipricals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sums_of_reciprocals))

The range of an int wraps, and so you would also be adding -1/1 -1/2 ... which would tend to 0.

The series progresses to infinity very slowly, so a computer may not be the best way of working it out.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for that :)