# c primer plus chapter 6 ex12

Tags: c

everyone,c primer plus chapter 6 ex12:

> **Consider these two infinite series:
>
> 1.0 + 1.0/2.0 + 1.0/3.0 + 1.0/4.0 + ...
>
> 1.0 - 1.0/2.0 + 1.0/3.0 - 1.0/4.0 + ...
>
> Write a program that evaluates running totals of these two series up to some limit of
>   number of terms. Hint: –1 times itself an odd number of times is –1, and –1 times itself
>   an even number of times is 1. Have the user enter the limit interactively; let a zero or
>   negative value terminate input. Look at the running totals after 100 terms, 1000 terms,
>   10,000 terms. Does either series appear to be converging to some value?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int times, a, b, d;
    float sum1, sum2, c;
    printf("Enter the times: ");
    scanf("%d", &times);
    while (times > 0)
    {
        sum1 = 0;
        sum2 = 0;

        for (a = times; a >= 1; a--)
            sum1 += 1.0 / (float)a;
        printf("The sum1 is %f\n", sum1);


        for (b = times; b >= 1; b--)
        {
            c = -1.0;
            while ((d = b) % 2 == 1)
            { 
                c = 1.0;
                d++;
            }
            sum2 += (c / (float)b);
        }
        printf("The sum2 is %f\n", sum2);

        printf("Enter the times again: ");
        scanf("%d", &times);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what's wrong about my code?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this algorithm to find the sum to infinity of a series acceptable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861210/is-this-algorithm-to-find-the-sum-to-infinity-of-a-series-acceptable)

Comment: You need to describe at least till what limit it works fine or whether it works at all

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
while ((d = b) % 2 == 1)
{ 
  c = 1.0;
  d++;
}
```

You assign the value of `b` to `d` (by `d = b`), then, you check if this value modulo 2 is equal to 1. If it's the case, you go inside your loop forever as the value of `b` never changes. Of course you increment `d` inside your loop, but in your check, you reset its value to `b`, leading to an infinite loop.

Regarding your exercice, you're trying to set `c` to `-1` if `b` is even and to 1 is b is odd. This can easily be done with a conditional assignment :

```
c = (b % 2 == 0) ? -1.0 : 1.0;
```

Or, as the hint in your question suggests, you can initialize `c` to `1` (or `-1`) before you ener the loop and do `c = -1.0 * c` inside