# How can a SwiftUI View adjust its ideal size in one dimension when the other dimension is clamped?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can a `View` adjust its ideal size in one dimension when the other dimension is clamped?

For instance, `Text` exhibits this behavior. If constrained via `.fixedSize` and given too little space in one dimension, then the ideal size for the other dimension will grow in response, if possible.

**Using** `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: false)`

[image]

**Using** `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`

[image]

**Using** `.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)`

[image]

It looks like `Text` has somehow defined its ideal size as something like `.frame(idealWidth: 400, idealHeight: 20)` in the first two cases. However, the part that's confusing me is that it seems to be modifying that in the third case to something like `.frame(idealWidth: 80, idealHeight: 100)`.

How can we, like `Text`, allow our `View` to update its ideal size in response to a dimension(s) being clamped?

Here's a bit of code that shows this behavior in `Text` which I described above:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 100) {
    Group {
        Text("ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo")
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: false)
        Text("ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo")
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
        Text("ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo")
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
    .background(Color.green)
    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
    .background(Color.blue)
}
```

With this font and repeating "o" content, `Text` wants to basically have square space equal to about 7,000 points (338x20 ideal size for case #2 and 68x108 for case #3).

How could this be replicated in a custom `View`? The `minHeight` and `minWidth` are not static; They depend on the parent having clamped a dimension or not. How can we, as the child, know which dimensions we've been clamped in, if any? The proposed size from the parent is still 75x75 in each example, so what is it that the child view has access to with which to base its ideal size off of? How is `Text` doing this?

To make an answer more concrete, consider how you could replace the `Text("oooooo")` instances with instances of a custom class which behaves similarly with regard to `.fixedSize`. ie. attempt to maintain a 7,000 point square area, with a minimum 20 point height, preferring to grow horizontally first.

Comment: The question is not clear (or too generic), would you show demo code of problem or elaborate what do you try to achieve?

Comment: @Asperi I've added some concrete code and elaborated on my question. Thanks for the feedback and for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

It's problematic due to the nature how the `fixedSize` works:

- We can provide `min`, `ideal` and `max` values for the `width` & `height` where `min <= ideal <= max`.
- We have to provide them upfront which is impossible because the `ideal` values will differ for horizontal/vertical fix.

### GeometryReader wrapper

[image]

The commented code is self explanatory.

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func frame(size: CGSize) -> some View {
        self.frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
}

struct TextLike: View {
    // It's like text, how much space we'd like to occupy
    var squareArea: CGFloat

    // Text() draws at least one line of text, we'll do the same
    private let preferredHeight: CGFloat = 20

    // Preferred/Max width in case of one line of text
    private let preferredWidth: CGFloat

    init(squareArea: CGFloat) {
        self.squareArea = squareArea
        self.preferredWidth = squareArea / preferredHeight
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            // Let's say that this is the text
            Color.green.opacity(0.5)
                .frame(size: self.size(withProxy: proxy))
        }
        .frame(
            // Ideally we'd like to draw it as one line of text
            idealWidth: preferredWidth,
            // Maximum width equals to ideal width (one line of text)
            maxWidth: preferredWidth,
            // At least one line of text
            minHeight: preferredHeight,
            // Ideally we'd like to draw it as one line of text
            idealHeight: preferredHeight
        )
    }

    private func size(withProxy proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGSize {
        //
        // Good enough for the demonstration, but you should get PhD & read:
        //
        //   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html
        //   https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335601/581190
        //   https://stackoverflow.com/a/10334868/581190
        //
        // Also it must be generic enough to cover different devices, ...
        //
        //   proxy.size.width on iPhone SE (2nd) = 350.0
        //   proxy.size.width on iPhone 11 Pro Max = 350.3333...
        //
        // Just be aware of this and provide proper logic.
        //
        let horizontalFix = abs(proxy.size.width.distance(to: preferredWidth)).isLessThanOrEqualTo(1.0)
        let verticalFix = abs(proxy.size.height.distance(to: preferredHeight)).isLessThanOrEqualTo(1.0)

        switch (horizontalFix, verticalFix) {
        case (true, _):
            // Horizontal fix -> use preferred (= max) width -> one line of text
            // Vertical is irrelevant, because we do prefer horizontal grow
            return CGSize(width: preferredWidth, height: preferredHeight)
        case (false, false):
            // Use the offered size -> fits container, possible truncation
            return proxy.size
        case (false, true):
            // Vertical fix -> use offered width & calculate height
            return CGSize(width: proxy.size.width, height: squareArea / proxy.size.width)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            Group {
                TextLike(squareArea: 7000)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: false)
                TextLike(squareArea: 7000)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                TextLike(squareArea: 7000)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                TextLike(squareArea: 7000)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
            }
            .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
            .background(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

### Problems

- `TextLike` acts as a wrapper and the actual view is in it (one additional layer).
- We can't use `background` modifier on it for example.

Let's modify the code and use the `background` modifier on the `TextLike` level like you did.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            Group {
                TextLike(squareArea: 7000)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: false)
                TextLike(squareArea: 7000)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                TextLike(squareArea: 7000)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                TextLike(squareArea: 7000)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
            }
            .background(Color.red.opacity(0.2))
            .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
            .background(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

This is what happens:

[image]

Frankly speaking, not ideal & nice, but closest I can get for now.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. You're right, it's unfortunate that the structure doesn't play well with `background`. As an aside, (and this is just an Xcode issue) Xcode canvas previews is really not having a good time with `LikeView` (as of Xcode 11.4). If someone doesn't come up with a solution without the background issue soon, I'll be sure to mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Bounty expires in 4 days, don't mark it yet. I'm still researching it if there's a better way in just pure SwiftUI.